# What's the best way to select the minimum value from several columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, min

Given the following table in SQL Server 2005:

```
ID   Col1   Col2   Col3
--   ----   ----   ----
1       3     34     76  
2      32    976     24
3       7    235      3
4     245      1    792
```

What is the best way to write the query that yields the following result (i.e. one that yields the final column - a column containing the minium values out of Col1, Col2, and Col 3 **for each row**)?

```
ID   Col1   Col2   Col3  TheMin
--   ----   ----   ----  ------
1       3     34     76       3
2      32    976     24      24
3       7    235      3       3
4     245      1    792       1
```

***UPDATE:***

For clarification (as I have said in the coments) in the real scenario the database is **properly normalized**. These "array" columns are not in an actual table but are in a result set that is required in a report. And the new requirement is that the report also needs this MinValue column. I can't change the underlying result set and therefore I was looking to T-SQL for a handy "get out of jail card".

I tried the CASE approach mentioned below and it works, although it is a bit cumbersome. It is also more complicated than stated in the answers because you need to cater for the fact that there are two min values in the same row.

Anyway, I thought I'd post my current solution which, given my constraints, works pretty well. It uses the UNPIVOT operator:

```
with cte (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
as
(
    select ID, Col1, Col2, Col3
    from TestTable
)
select cte.ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, TheMin from cte
join
(
    select
        ID, min(Amount) as TheMin
    from 
        cte 
        UNPIVOT (Amount for AmountCol in (Col1, Col2, Col3)) as unpvt
    group by ID
) as minValues
on cte.ID = minValues.ID
```

I'll say upfront that I don't expect this to offer the best performance, but given the circumstances (I can't redesign all the queries just for the new MinValue column requirement), it is a pretty elegant "get out of jail card".

Comment: IMHO the author's UNPIVOT solution is superior to the other answers.

Comment: I find Nizam's solution to be the leanest solution, even if it took me a while to start understanding it. Lean and very usable.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There are likely to be many ways to accomplish this.  My suggestion is to use Case/When to do it.  With 3 columns, it's not too bad.

```
Select Id,
       Case When Col1 < Col2 And Col1 < Col3 Then Col1
            When Col2 < Col1 And Col2 < Col3 Then Col2 
            Else Col3
            End As TheMin
From   YourTableNameHere
```

Comment: This was my initial thought. But the real query needs 5 columns, and the number of columns could grow. So the CASE approach becomes a little unwieldy. But it does work.

Comment: If the number of columns could grow, you're *definitely* doing it wrong - see my post (the rant on why you shouldn't have your DB schema set up this way :-).

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in another comment. I'm not querying actual tables. The tables are normalised correctly. This query is part of a particularly complex query and is working on intermediate results from derived tables.

Comment: In that case, can you derive them differently so they look normalized?

Comment: I'd be very circumspect about using this on any decent-sized table. SELECTs that perform functions on every row are notoriously unscalable. Assuming your row count is small enough, this won't matter but it will cause troubles on large databases.

Comment: An add on to the answer from @Gmastros as I ran into the issue that some of the Cols had matching data so I had to add the = sign. My data also had the potential for null so I had to add in the or statement to account for that. There maybe an easier way to do this but I have not found one in the past 6 months I have been looking. Thanks to everyone involved here.

Select Id,
CaseWhen (Col1 <= Col2 OR Col2 is null) And (Col1 <= Col3 OR Col3 is null) Then Col1
When (Col2 <= Col1 OR Col1 is null) And (Col2 <= Col3 OR Col3 is null) Then Col2 
Else Col3
End As TheMin
From   YourTableNameHere

Comment: This answer is wrong, as it doesn't take account of nulls or columns with equal values.   See the comment from @ChadPortman

Answer (score 76):

Using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, MinValue
FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(d) AS MinValue FROM (VALUES (Col1), (Col2), (Col3)) AS a(d)) A
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbbd3/1)

Comment: Looks interesting but I can't get this to work. Could you perhaps explicit a bit ? thx

Comment: @iDevlop I inserted the SQL Fiddle in my answer

Comment: The thing I did not know was the scalar function. It seems that your answer works also without the `cross apply`. Does it add value/performance ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14712024/78522

Comment: @iDevlop If it not delivers performance, it increases readbility. For example, I could use something like `where MinValue > 10`, which I could not do without `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: indeed, I had the opportunity to understand the "reusability" benefit of it in the meantime. Thanks. I learned 2 things today ;-)

Comment: Thank you from 2017! I just need to adjust this a bit more.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez with `CROSS APPLY` you can reference the result inside the WHERE clause and afterwards (GROUP BY, HAVING, WINDOW, SELECT and ORDER BY...you can even reference it inside JOIN). If used inside `SELECT` you can access it inside ORDER BY.

Comment: This solution appears to be RDBMS dependent. For example, SQL Fiddle works for MS SQL, but fails for all others - MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite. I also tested on my GBQ instance and it fails there as well

Answer (score 68):

```
SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, 
    (SELECT MIN(Col) FROM (VALUES (Col1), (Col2), (Col3)) AS X(Col)) AS TheMin
FROM Table
```

The OP was tagged as `sql-server`, and this is an SQL Server specific answer.  May not work on other DBMSs.  (Search for `least` for Postgres derived DBs and some others).

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I'd missed that tag.  I actually don't know, and don't have the ability to test it either.  Will be more dilligent in checking tags going forward.

Comment: Hands down the more elegant solution - not sure why it doesn't have more upvotes.

Comment: For inline max/min calcs this is by far the best way to do this

Comment: In 2022, this solution doesn't work for Google BigQuery - perhaps that's also the case for other RDBMS. Error is 'Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ","'

Comment: @magiclantern The OP is tagged with sql-server, so the answer is sql-server.

Answer (score 30):

On MySQL, use this:

```
select least(col1, col2, col3) FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Might not be an SQL statement.

Comment: but in some cases it is. for those, this is a wonderful answer

Comment: Available in Postgres since 8.1: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-conditional.html#AEN12704

Comment: This non-standard SQL extension is supported by pretty much every database except Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: `LEAST` works in the latest version of Microsoft SQL Server Managed Instances, as of ~12 days ago.  https://www.reddit.com/r/SQLServer/comments/k0dj2r/what_the_heck_when_did_sql_server_start/

Comment: Works in Informix as well, thank you for the answer.

Comment: The question is about SQL Server which doesn't have this function.

Comment: For any readers using SQLLite, The `min` function works like `least` in SQLLite, but takes NULL if _any_ value is NULL. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166690/sqlite-equivalent-of-postgresqls-greatest-function).

Comment: The opposite is `GREATEST`

Answer (score 16):

As of SQL Server 2022, you can use the [`LEAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) function for this. There is also the [`GREATEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) function.

---

For earlier versions, you can use the "brute force" approach with a twist:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN Col1 <= Col2 AND Col1 <= Col3 THEN Col1
    WHEN                  Col2 <= Col3 THEN Col2
    ELSE                                    Col3
END AS [Min Value] FROM [Your Table]
```

When the first when condition fails it guarantees that Col1 is not the smallest value therefore you can eliminate it from rest of the conditions. Likewise for subsequent conditions. For five columns your query becomes:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN Col1 <= Col2 AND Col1 <= Col3 AND Col1 <= Col4 AND Col1 <= Col5 THEN Col1
    WHEN                  Col2 <= Col3 AND Col2 <= Col4 AND Col2 <= Col5 THEN Col2
    WHEN                                   Col3 <= Col4 AND Col3 <= Col5 THEN Col3
    WHEN                                                    Col4 <= Col5 THEN Col4
    ELSE                                                                      Col5
END AS [Min Value] FROM [Your Table]
```

Note that if there is a tie between two or more columns then `<=` ensures that we exit the `CASE` statement as early as possible.

Comment: Use `<=` instead, otherwise, the last matching min value will be used instead of the first.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do that is probably *not* to do it - it's strange that people insist on storing their data in a way that requires SQL "gymnastics" to extract meaningful information, when there are far easier ways to achieve the desired result if you just structure your schema a little better :-)

The *right* way to do this, in my opinion, is to have the following table:

```
ID    Col    Val
--    ---    ---
 1      1      3
 1      2     34
 1      3     76

 2      1     32
 2      2    976
 2      3     24

 3      1      7
 3      2    235
 3      3      3

 4      1    245
 4      2      1
 4      3    792
```

with `ID/Col` as the primary key (and possibly `Col` as an extra key, depending on your needs). Then your query becomes a simple `select min(val) from tbl` and you can still treat the individual 'old columns' separately by using `where col = 2` in your other queries. This also allows for easy expansion should the number of 'old columns' grow.

This makes your queries *so* much easier. The general guideline I tend to use is, if you *ever* have something that looks like an array in a database row, you're probably doing something wrong and should think about restructuring the data.

---

However, if for some reason you *can't* change those columns, I'd suggest using insert and update triggers and add *another* column which these triggers set to the minimum on `Col1/2/3`. This will move the 'cost' of the operation away from the select to the update/insert where it belongs - most database tables in my experience are read far more often than written so incurring the cost on write tends to be more efficient over time.

In other words, the minimum for a row only changes when one of the other columns change, so *that's* when you should be calculating it, not every time you select (which is wasted if the data isn't changing). You would then end up with a table like:

```
ID   Col1   Col2   Col3   MinVal
--   ----   ----   ----   ------
 1      3     34     76        3
 2     32    976     24       24
 3      7    235      3        3
 4    245      1    792        1
```

Any other option that has to make decisions at `select` time is usually a bad idea performance-wise, since the data only changes on insert/update - the addition of another column takes up more space in the DB and will be slightly slower for the inserts and updates but can be *much* faster for selects - the preferred approach should depend on your priorities there but, as stated, most tables are read *far* more often than they're written.

Comment: Um. Thanks for the diatribe. The real database is properly normalized. This was a simple example. The actual query is complicated and the 5 columns I am interested in are intermediate results from derived tables.

Comment: The diatribe still stands unfortunately. Making intermediate tables of the form you suggest is every bit as problematic as making permanent tables like that. This is evidenced by the fact that you have to perform what I like to call SQL gymnastics to get the result you want.

Comment: If there are genuine reasons for needing the 'array' in a single row, feel free to enlighten us, but using it to select the minimum value is not one of them.

Comment: +1 for the trigger suggestion to preserve the original (if flawed) table structure.

Comment: What if you are dealing with a Hierarchy table, joined to it self?

Comment: Hi please explain how a table with one key and 5 numeric properties is not properly normalized.  It seems to be exactly in the meet the definition through at least the third normal form.

Answer (score 6):

If the columns were integers as in your example I would create a function:

```
create function f_min_int(@a as int, @b as int) 
returns int
as
begin
    return case when @a < @b then @a else coalesce(@b,@a) end
end
```

then when I need to use it I would do :

```
select col1, col2, col3, dbo.f_min_int(dbo.f_min_int(col1,col2),col3)
```

if you have 5 colums then the above becomes

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
dbo.f_min_int(dbo.f_min_int(dbo.f_min_int(dbo.f_min_int(col1,col2),col3),col4),col5)
```

Comment: Given the ridiculously bad performance of scalar functions in MSSQL I'm feeling obliged to advice against this approach. If you'd go this road than at least write a function that takes all 5 columns as parameters at once. It's still going to be bad, but at least a bit less bad =/

Comment: Recursion will reduce the performance. But it will meet the requirement.

Answer (score 5):

This is brute force but works

```
 select case when col1 <= col2 and col1 <= col3 then col1
           case when col2 <= col1 and col2 <= col3 then col2
           case when col3 <= col1 and col3 <= col2 then col3
    as 'TheMin'
           end

from Table T
```

... because min() works only on one column and not across columns.

Comment: It also tends to be the fastest since MIN creates implicit nested loop join.

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this with a union query.  As the number of columns increase, you would need to modify the query, but at least it would be a straight forward modification.

```
Select T.Id, T.Col1, T.Col2, T.Col3, A.TheMin
From   YourTable T
       Inner Join (
         Select A.Id, Min(A.Col1) As TheMin
         From   (
                Select Id, Col1
                From   YourTable

                Union All

                Select Id, Col2
                From   YourTable

                Union All

                Select Id, Col3
                From   YourTable
                ) As A
         Group By A.Id
       ) As A
       On T.Id = A.Id
```

Comment: This works but performance will degrade when the row count rises.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this works. As Tomalak says, in my realword query this would be quite nasty for performance. But +1 for effort. :)

Answer (score 2):

Both [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196256/returning-the-largest-of-2-columns-in-sql-server-closed) 
And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-mathmax-in-net) try to answer this.

The recap is that Oracle has a built in function for this, with Sql Server you are stuck either defining a user-defined-function or using case statements.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple columns its best to use a CASE statement, however for two numeric columns i and j you can use simple math:

min(i,j) = (i+j)/2 - abs(i-j)/2

This formula can be used to get the minimum value of multiple columns but its really messy past 2, min(i,j,k) would be min(i,min(j,k))

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to make a stored procedure, it could take an array of values, and you could just call that.

Comment: Oracle has a function called LEAST() that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for rubbing that in :)
I can't believe that SQL Server doesn't have an equivalent!

Comment: I was even going to say, "Hey, my favourite pgsql doesn't have it either," but it actually does.  ;)  The function itself wouldn't be tough to write though.

Comment: Oh, except that T-SQL doesn't even have array support (???)  Well, I guess you could have a five-parameter function and if you need more just extend it...

Answer (score 1):

```
select *,
case when column1 < columnl2 And column1 < column3 then column1
when columnl2 < column1 And columnl2 < column3 then columnl2
else column3
end As minValue
from   tbl_example
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of G Mastros' answer, so if you should wonder: I guess that's where down-vote comes from.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL 2005 you can do something neat like this:

```
;WITH    res
          AS ( SELECT   t.YourID ,
                        CAST(( SELECT   Col1 AS c01 ,
                                        Col2 AS c02 ,
                                        Col3 AS c03 ,
                                        Col4 AS c04 ,
                                        Col5 AS c05
                               FROM     YourTable AS cols
                               WHERE    YourID = t.YourID
                             FOR
                               XML AUTO ,
                                   ELEMENTS
                             ) AS XML) AS colslist
               FROM     YourTable AS t
             )
    SELECT  YourID ,
            colslist.query('for $c in //cols return min(data($c/*))').value('.',
                                            'real') AS YourMin ,
            colslist.query('for $c in //cols return avg(data($c/*))').value('.',
                                            'real') AS YourAvg ,
            colslist.query('for $c in //cols return max(data($c/*))').value('.',
                                            'real') AS YourMax
    FROM    res
```

This way you don't get lost in so many operators :)

However, this could be slower than the other choice.

It's your choice...

Comment: Well, like I said, this could be slow, but if you have too many columns (obviously, as a result of a really bad DB design!), it could worth using this (at least for AVG). You didn't give me any hint if it's a good *holy cow* or a bad one:) Maybe you should use the up/down vote to help me figure out.

Comment: It wasn't really a good or a bad one ;). I'm no database expert, so I was just saying "holy cow" because the question seemed like it would have a trivial answer. I guess it's a good one since you managed to provide a flexible, extensible solution to the problem!

Answer (score 1):

A little twist on the union query:

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE (ID INT, Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)

INSERT @Foo (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
(1, 3, 34, 76),
(2, 32, 976, 24),
(3, 7, 235, 3),
(4, 245, 1, 792)

SELECT
    ID,
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3,
    (
        SELECT MIN(T.Col)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT Foo.Col1 AS Col UNION ALL
            SELECT Foo.Col2 AS Col UNION ALL
            SELECT Foo.Col3 AS Col 
        ) AS T
    ) AS TheMin
FROM
    @Foo AS Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what values you are looking for, usually a status code, the following can be helpful:

```
select case when 0 in (PAGE1STATUS ,PAGE2STATUS ,PAGE3STATUS,
PAGE4STATUS,PAGE5STATUS ,PAGE6STATUS) then 0 else 1 end
FROM CUSTOMERS_FORMS
```

Answer (score 1):

Below I use a temp table to get the minimum of several dates. The first temp table queries several joined tables to get various dates (as well as other values for the query), the second temp table then gets the various columns and the minimum date using as many passes as there are date columns.

This is essentially like the union query, the same number of passes are required, but may be more efficient (based on experience, but would need testing). Efficiency wasn't an issue in this case (8,000 records). One could index etc.

```
--==================== this gets minimums and global min
if object_id('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
    drop table #temp1
if object_id('tempdb..#temp2') is not null
    drop table #temp2

select r.recordid ,  r.ReferenceNumber, i.InventionTitle, RecordDate, i.ReceivedDate
, min(fi.uploaddate) [Min File Upload], min(fi.CorrespondenceDate) [Min File Correspondence]
into #temp1
from record r 
join Invention i on i.inventionid = r.recordid
left join LnkRecordFile lrf on lrf.recordid = r.recordid
left join fileinformation fi on fi.fileid = lrf.fileid
where r.recorddate > '2015-05-26'
 group by  r.recordid, recorddate, i.ReceivedDate,
 r.ReferenceNumber, i.InventionTitle



select recordid, recorddate [min date]
into #temp2
from #temp1

update #temp2
set [min date] = ReceivedDate 
from #temp1 t1 join #temp2 t2 on t1.recordid = t2.recordid
where t1.ReceivedDate < [min date] and  t1.ReceivedDate > '2001-01-01'

update #temp2 
set [min date] = t1.[Min File Upload]
from #temp1 t1 join #temp2 t2 on t1.recordid = t2.recordid
where t1.[Min File Upload] < [min date] and  t1.[Min File Upload] > '2001-01-01'

update #temp2
set [min date] = t1.[Min File Correspondence]
from #temp1 t1 join #temp2 t2 on t1.recordid = t2.recordid
where t1.[Min File Correspondence] < [min date] and t1.[Min File Correspondence] > '2001-01-01'


select t1.*, t2.[min date] [LOWEST DATE]
from #temp1 t1 join #temp2 t2 on t1.recordid = t2.recordid
order by t1.recordid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [ID],
            (
                SELECT MIN([value].[MinValue])
                FROM
                (
                    VALUES
                        ([Col1]),
                        ([Col1]),
                        ([Col2]),
                        ([Col3])
                ) AS [value] ([MinValue])
           ) AS [MinValue]
FROM Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is old, but I was still in the need of the answer and was not happy with other answers so I had to devise my own which is a twist on @paxdiablo´s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/368394/3336667).

---

I came from land of SAP ASE 16.0, and I only needed a peek at statistics of certain data which are IMHO validly stored in different columns of a single row (they represent different times - when arrival of something was planned, what it was expected when the action started and finally what was the actual time). Thus I had transposed columns into the rows of temporary table and preformed my query over this as usually.

N.B. **Not the one-size-fits-all solution ahead!**

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable (ID int, columnName varchar(20), dataValue int)

INSERT INTO #tempTable 
  SELECT ID, 'Col1', Col1
    FROM sourceTable
   WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL
INSERT INTO #tempTable 
  SELECT ID, 'Col2', Col2
    FROM sourceTable
   WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL
INSERT INTO #tempTable 
  SELECT ID, 'Col3', Col3
    FROM sourceTable
   WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL

SELECT ID
     , min(dataValue) AS 'Min'
     , max(dataValue) AS 'Max'
     , max(dataValue) - min(dataValue) AS 'Diff' 
  FROM #tempTable 
  GROUP BY ID
```

This took some 30 seconds on source set of 630000 rows and used only index-data, so not the thing to run in time-critical process but for things like one-time data inspection or end-of-the-day report you might be fine (but verify this with your peers or superiors, please!).
Main bonus of this style *for me* was that I could readily use more/less columns and change grouping, filtering, etc., especially once data was copyied over.

The additional data (`columnName`, `max`es, ...) were to aid me in my search, so you might not need them; I left them here to maybe spark some ideas :-).

Answer (score 0):

case
when Col1 < Col2 and Col1 < Col3
then Col1
when Col2 is null and Col3 is null
then Col1
when Col1 < Col2 and Col3 is null
then Col1
when Col1 < Col3 and Col2 is null
then Col1
when Col2 < Col1 and  Col2 < Col3
then Col2
when Col1 is null and Col3 is null
then Col2
when Col2 < Col1 and Col3 is null
then Col2
when Col2 < Col3 and Col1 is null
then Col2
when Col3 < Col1 and Col3 < Col2
then Col3
when Col1 is null and Col2 is null
then Col3
when Col3 < Col1 and Col2 is null
then Col3
when Col3 < Col2 and Col1 is null
then Col3
when Col2 = Col3
then Col2
when Col1 = Col3
then Col1
when Col1 = Col2
then Col1
when Col2 = Col3 and Col1 = Col3
then Col1
else null end as 'MIN'

Comment: This was the only way I could successfully do it with 3 columns with null values

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2022 (and Azure SQL Database), you can use `LEAST()` function.

```
SELECT LEAST('6.62', 3.1415, N'7') AS LeastVal;
SELECT LEAST('Glacier', N'Joshua Tree', 'Mount Rainier') AS LeastString;

SELECT 
    LEAST(P.SellStartDate, P.OtherDate, P.ThirdDate) AS EarliestDate
FROM SalesLT.Product AS P
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest