# SQLite equivalent of PostgreSQL's GREATEST function

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

PostgreSQL has a useful function called `GREATEST`. It returns the largest value of those passed to it as documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-conditional.html).

Is there any equivalent in SQLite?

*As a note, I only need it to work with 2 arguments.*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`SELECT MAX(1,2,..)`

ref: https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc

> **`max(X,Y,...)`**
>
> The multi-argument max() function returns the argument with the maximum value, or return NULL if any argument is NULL. The multi-argument max() function searches its arguments from left to right for an argument that defines a collating function and uses that collating function for all string comparisons. If none of the arguments to max() define a collating function, then the BINARY collating function is used. Note that max() is a simple function when it has 2 or more arguments but operates as an aggregate function if given only a single argument.

Comment: Ok, can someone explain strange behavior of max function with strings. select max ('rb','VISA', 'Visa', 'Visa Card1', 'VISA VISA Card', 'Visaaa') returns 'rb', Why?!?

Comment: @zlatko: sounds like a case-sensitive comparison.  lowercase is coming after uppercase.

Comment: @zlatko - check out an ASCII chart!

Comment: Be careful, the behavior with NULL is different: PostgreSQL `GREATEST` returns NULL only if _all_ arguments are NULL. SQLite `MAX` returns NULL if _any_ argument is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

using a second value in `MAX(value1, value2)` would be the equivalent 
Example:

```
UPDATE products SET Quantity = MAX(Quantity - @value, 0)...
```

if (`Quantity - value`) return a **"Negative Number `-0`"** then **`Max( , 0)`** will return **0** 
 because 0 is bigger than -0 / -1 / -2 ... and so on 
**`Max( , 1)`** will return **1** if the same condition (`Quantity - value`) return **0** or a Negative Number .. etc, you get the idea !

> if we assume that both `Quantity` and `@value` could be **NULL** then use the combination: `IFNULL(MAX(Quantity-@value,0),0)`
> `IFNULL(..., 0)` will return the second value of your choice **IF** the first one is **NULL**