# SQL - Getting Most Recent Date From Multiple Columns

Tags: sql

Assume a rowset containing the following

```
EntryID    Name      DateModified   DateDeleted
-----------------------------------------------  
1          Name1     1/2/2003       NULL
2          Name1     1/3/2005       1/5/2008
3          Name1     1/3/2006       NULL
4          Name1     NULL           NULL  
5          Name1     3/5/2008       NULL
```

*Clarification:*

I need a single value - the largest non-null date from BOTH columns. So the largest of all ten cells in this case.

Comment: Are you asking for the largest value from *either* DateModified *or* DateDeleted or do you want to largest value *for each* column?

Comment: @OMG - does that make a difference?
@Thomas - I have edited my question; just one value from both columns

Comment: I think the reason for @OMG's question was to know whether the `GREATEST` function would be available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN (DateDeleted IS NULL OR DateModified > DateDeleted)
                THEN DateModified ELSE DateDeleted END) AS MaxDate
FROM Table
```

Comment: That would need to be `CASE WHEN ISNULL(DateModified, 0) > ISNULL(DateDeleted, 0)` I think

Answer (score 9):

For MySQL, Postgres or Oracle, use the GREATEST function:

```
SELECT GREATEST(ISNULL(t.datemodified, '1900-01-01 00:00:00'),  
                ISNULL(t.datedeleted, '1900-01-01 00:00:00'))
  FROM TABLE t
```

Both Oracle and MySQL will return NULL if a NULL is provided.  The example uses MySQL null handling - update accordingly for the appropriate database.

A database agnostic alternative is:

```
SELECT z.entryid,
       MAX(z.dt)
  FROM (SELECT x.entryid,
               x.datemodified AS dt
          FROM TABLE x
        UNION ALL
        SELECT y.entryid
               y.datedeleted AS dt
          FROM TABLE y) z
GROUP BY z.entryid
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the `GREATEST` function, plus, I like your database agnostic solution. =)

Comment: +1 for the `GREATEST` function. That makes things a lot easier (assuming his database supports it)!

Comment: Your first solution does not work. 1) Greatest is not an aggregate function, it returns a result per row, so need `MAX(GREATEST(...)` 2) Except that (at least on Oracle) `GREATEST(some_value, NULL)` returns `NULL`, so would not meet the specific needs of OP.

Comment: FYI: SQLite GREATEST equivalent (which isn't supported by SQL Server or MySQL btw): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166690/sqlite-equivilant-of-postgresql-greatest-function

Comment: @Shannon Severance: The OP isn't asking for an aggregate.  MySQL also returns NULL if comparing dates; I provided MySQL syntax because it's the most likely vendor.

Comment: SQL Server supports GREATEST

Answer (score 4):

As a general solution, you could try something like this:

```
select max(date_col)
from(
  select max(date_col1) AS date_col from some_table
  union
  select max(date_col2) AS date_col from some_table
  union
  select max(date_col3) AS date_col from some_table
  ...
)
```

There might be easier ways, depending on what database you're using.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you really want. If you simply want the most recent of the two date values then you can do:

```
Select Max(DateModified), Max(DateDeleted)
From Table
```

If you are asking for the largest value from *either column*, then you can simply do:

```
Select Case 
        When Max(DateModified) > Max(DateDeleted) Then Max(DateModified)
        Else Max(DateDeleted)
        End As MaxOfEitherValue
From Table
```

Answer (score 2):

How about;

```
SELECT MAX(MX) FROM (
    SELECT MAX(DateModified) AS MX FROM Tbl
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(DateDeleted) FROM Tbl
) T
```

Comment: Simple, works with most databases and multiple tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

The above are all valid answers;

But I'm Not sure if this would work?

```
select IsNull((
                select MAX(DateModified) 
                from table
              )
             ,
              (
                 select MAX(DateDeleted) 
                 from table
              )
             )     as MaxOfEitherValue
from    table
```

**Edit 1:**

Whilst in the shower this morning, I had another solution:

### Solution 2:

```
  select MAX(v) from (
                       select MAX(DateModified) as v from table
                       union all
                       select MAX(DateDeleted) as v from table
                     ) as SubTable
```

**Edit 3:**

Damn it, just spotted this is the same solution as Alex k. sigh...

Comment: No this wouldn't work in the case that both were not null. Also the `from table` means it will return multiple rows.

Answer (score -1):

How to find the Latest Date from the columns from Multiple tables
e.g. if the Firstname is in Table1, Address is in Table2, Phone is in Table3:

When you are using with main SELECT statement while selecting other columns it is best written as :

```
SELECT Firstname
,Lastname
,Address
,PhoneNumber
,

,(SELECT max(T.date_col) from(select max(date_col1) AS date_col from Table1 Where ..
                               union
                               select max(date_col2) AS date_col from Table2 Where..
                               union
                               select max(date_col3) AS date_col from Table3 Where..
                               ) AS T
   ) AS Last_Updated_Date

FROM Table T1
LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON T1.Common_Column=T2.Common_Column
LEFTJOIN Table T3 ON T1.Common_Column=T3.Common_Column
```