# query to sort rowwise in sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

i have a table with say 2 columns of varchar type. i want to query to sort them rowwise in SQLlite.

eg:
    Table

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2
book     apple
lemon    mango
google   amazon
```

the query should return me this:

```
apple    book
lemon    mango
amazon   google
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite, you can do this using the MIN and MAX functions, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166690/sqlite-equivilant-of-postgresql-greatest-function)

```
SELECT MIN(column1, column2), MAX(column1, column2) FROM mytable
```

You originally didn't specify the DB type, so I wrote this for MySQL. The logic applies to others as well, though the functions may differ.

```
SELECT LEAST (column1, column2), GREATEST(column1, column2) FROM mytable
```

- [GREATEST function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)
- [LEAST function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

Comment: Updated my answer for SQLite. And next time please tag your question with the DB you're using to get better specialised help and quicker...