# Get the minimum value between several columns

Tags: sql-server, datetime, min

I'm using SQL Server 2008;

Suppose I have a table 'X' with columns 'Date1', 'Date2', 'Dateblah', all of type DateTime.

I want to select the min value between the three columns, for example (simplified, with date mm/dd/yyyy)

```
ID       Date1          Date2           Dateblah
0     09/29/2011      09/20/2011       09/01/2011 
1     01/01/2011      01/05/2011       03/03/2010

ID    MinDate
0    09/01/2011
1    03/03/2010
```

Is there a bread and butter command to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've seen this question [What's the best way to select the minimum value from several columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-minimum-value-from-multiple-columns) but unfortunately it won't suit me as I'm being obligated to do it against normalization because I'm making tfs work item reports, and the 'brute-force' case thing will end up being a pain if I have 6 ou 7 columns.

Comment: You (or anyone else reading this) might want to check a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55747020/3336667) at that question. Yes that answer is mine, but does not use repeatedly-mentioned answer of large switch, new function or changing tables, adding triggers etc., it uses temp table to transpose structure and then common `min` function. I am posting is comment as this is not answer by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built in function to return the min/max of two (or more) columns.  You could implement your own scalar function to do this.

In SQL Server 2005+ you could use [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) to turn the columns into rows and then use the MIN function:

```
CREATE TABLE [X]
(
    [ID] INT,
    [Date1] DATETIME,
    [Date2] DATETIME,
    [Date3] DATETIME
)

INSERT  [X]
VALUES  (0, '09/29/2011', '09/20/2011', '09/01/2011'),
        (1, '01/01/2011', '01/05/2011', '03/03/2010')


SELECT [ID], MIN([Date]) AS [MinDate]
FROM [X]
UNPIVOT (
    [Date] FOR d IN
        ([Date1]
        ,[Date2]
        ,[Date3])
) unpvt
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, I'll mark as answer as soon as I can

Comment: I just tried to run this code on my server (SQL SErver 2008 R2) and received an error related to the last statement.  "Incorrect syntax near 'Date'."

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting this.  Are you running the script through SQL Server Management Studio?  I just tried it again against a 2008 R2 instance and it works fine for me..

Comment: I think I figured out the issue.  I am not the db admin and it seems we have some sort of compatibly check in place that ensures some older code from 10 + years ago works correctly on the server I was working with.   I think this is preventing the unpivot command from working correctly. When I tired on a new server it worked correctly.

Comment: Yep, looks like your database compatibility level is set to 80 (SQL Server 2000) - I can re-create the error if I change mine to 80 (ALTER DATABASE [Tom] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80).  The code works with level 90 or 100 set.

Answer (score 9):

based on scalar function (from [Tom Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62072/tom-hunter)):

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT MIN([date]) FROM (VALUES(Date1),(Date2),(Dateblah)) x([date])) MinDate
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MIN](@a SQL_VARIANT, @b SQL_VARIANT)
RETURNS SQL_VARIANT
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT MIN([x])
        FROM (VALUES(@a),(@b)) x([x])
    )   
END
GO

DECLARE @a DATETIME = '12 JUL 2011', @b DATETIME = '20 AUG 2011'
SELECT [dbo].[MIN](@a, @b)

DECLARE @c INT = 12, @d INT = 32
SELECT [dbo].[MIN](@c, @d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply lets say the table where your dates are is called `sells` and it has two date fields `Date1` and `Date2` from which you want the minimum.

```
SELECT ( 
   SELECT MIN([x]) 
   FROM (VALUES(Date1),(Date2)) x([x])
) as minimum
FROM sells
```