# How to find the min of multiple values in HIVE?

Tags: hive, mapreduce, cloudera

Hive has min(col) to find the minimum value of a column. But how about finding the minimum of multiple values (NOT one column), for example

```
 select min(2,1,3,4);
```

returns

```
 FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException Exactly one argument is expected
```

Any tips?

Comment: kindly refer to these links - [exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276698/hive-finding-min-of-n-columns-in-a-row), [StackEx Discussion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-the-minimum-of-multiple-columns-on-sql-ser)

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution!

Instead of `min(col)`, we should use `least(a, b, c, d)`

Comment: just to add to this, the flip side the function for max is `greatest`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using MIN, use LEAST method to find the minimum values form given values/columns^^rows.

```
select least(2,1,3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below to find the minimum value from multiple columns.

It will produce minimum value from each row.

`select least(col1,col2) as least_value from table_name;`

It will produce minimum value from all rows.

`select min(least(col1,col2)) as least_value from table_name;`