# selecting minimum of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have three decimal columns named list1,list2,list3.
I want to find the minimum of three in a single query.
I've tired this:

```
SELECT Least(list1, list2, list3) 
FROM   table1
```

It throws an error that `least` is not recognized function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to select the minimum value from multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-minimum-value-from-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `UNION`

```
SELECT MIN(x.a)
FROM
    (
        SELECT list1 a FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT list2 a FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT list3 a FROM table1
    ) x
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT ID,MIN(x.a)
FROM
    (
        SELECT ID,list1 a FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT ID,list2 a FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT ID,list3 a FROM table1
    ) x
GROUP BY ID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a567/1)

Comment: i have one doubt, is least is function of sql right, then why it says that it is not a inbuilt function

Comment: No, not all RDBMS like yours supports `LEAST` function.

Comment: @Maddy what are talking about?

Comment: I have to side with @Maddy here, taking the least of 3 columns should not be done with the whole table, not the way the question was described. The least should only affect each row. I don't see how this solve the problem.

Comment: This will work it the table has a primary key or unique id. Take a look at Maddy's and my scripts, Those doesn't rely on primary keys and is slightly faster than your script.

Answer (score 4):

other solution,

```
case when col1 < col2 
     then case when col1 < col3 
               then col1
               else col3 end
     else case when col2 < col3
               then col2
               else col3 end;
```

Comment: this will work well with 3 columns, but with more than 3 it gets complicated. However i agree that it is a fast solution

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, You are write this might not be the best approch when there are more columns for comarison

Answer (score 1):

This will work if there is more than 1 row in the table

```
select c.mlist from table1 a
cross apply
(
select min(list1) mlist from
  (
    select list1
    union all
    select list2
    union all
    select list3
  ) b
) c
```

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2022 (and Azure SQL Database), you can use LEAST() function.

```
SELECT LEAST('6.62', 3.1415, N'7') AS LeastVal;
SELECT LEAST('Glacier', N'Joshua Tree', 'Mount Rainier') AS LeastString;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest