# How to search min value from four other different fields in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to search **min** value from four fields in mysql query, I have tried a lot of ways but didn't get it, right now I am searching only from one field,

here are my fields.

Table :packages

```
package_id        price   price_double    price_triple    price_quad
```

I want to search the min amount from four fields

like in php function

```
 min(price,price_double,price_triple,price_quad).
```

but I want to implement it in mysql query how can this be possible?
please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the minimum value across all four columns?

Comment: yes exactly i want to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

```
SELECT
    package_id,
    LEAST(price, price_double, price_triple, price_quad) AS price
FROM package;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select     case when price <= price_double and price <= price_triple and price<=price_quad then price
           when price_double <= price and price_double <= price_triple and price_double <=price_quad then price_double
          when price_triple<=price and price_triple<=price_double and pricetriple <= price_quad then price_triple
           when price_quad <= price and price_quad <= price_double and price_quad <=price_triple then price_quad
    end as 'TheMin'             

from Table packages
```

If you have any doubt please check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-minimum-value-from-multiple-columns) question link.

Comment: it getting me all rows min vlaue.

Answer (score 0):

what you think about that? is it right?

```
   SELECT LEAST(MIN(price), MIN(price_double), MIN(price_triple), MIN(price_quad))
   AS MinOfAllColumns
   FROM packages
```