# SQL: Select the minimum value from multiple columns with null values

Tags: sql, select

I have a table like this one

```
ID   Col1   Col2   Col3
--   ----   ----   ----
1      7    NULL    12  
2      2     46    NULL
3     NULL  NULL   NULL
4     245     1    792
```

I wanted  a query that yields the following result

```
 ID   Col1   Col2   Col3  MIN
 --   ----   ----   ----  ---
  1     7    NULL    12    7
  2     2     46    NULL   2
  3    NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL
  4    245    1     792    1
```

I mean, I wanted a column containing the minimum values out of Col1, Col2, and Col 3 for each row ignoring NULL values. In a previous question ([What's the best way to select the minimum value from multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-minimum-value-from-multiple-columns)) there is an answer for non NULL values. I need a query as efficient as possible for a huge table.

```
Select Id,
       Case When Col1 < Col2 And Col1 < Col3 Then Col1
            When Col2 < Col1 And Col2 < Col3 Then Col2 
            Else Col3
            End As MIN
From   YourTableNameHere
```

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you can define some "max" value (I'll use 9999 here) that your real values will never exceed:

```
Select Id,
       Case When Col1 < COALESCE(Col2, 9999)
             And Col1 < COALESCE(Col3, 9999) Then Col1
            When Col2 < COALESCE(Col1, 9999) 
             And Col2 < COALESCE(Col3, 9999) Then Col2 
            Else Col3
       End As MIN
    From YourTableNameHere;
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify which version of Teradata you're using. If you're using version 14+ then you can use [`least`](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Miscellaneous_Functions.096.39.html).

Unfortunately `least` will return null if any of its arguments are null. From the docs:

> LEAST supports 1-10 numeric values.
>   If numeric_value is the data type of the first argument, the return
>   data type is numeric. The remaining arguments in the input list must
>   be the same or compatible types. If either input parameter is NULL,
>   NULL is returned.

But you can get around that by using `coalesce` as Joe did in his answer.

```
select id, 
  least(coalesce(col1,9999),coalesce(col2,9999),coalesce(col3,9999))
from mytable
```

Comment: made my day.. was looking similar in bigquery.. it worked

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to be more efficient than using multiple case statement clauses, which can get extremely lengthy when evaluating data from several columns across one row.

Also, I can't take credit for this solution as I found it on some website a year or so ago. Today I needed a refresh on this logic, and I couldn't find it anywhere. I found my old code and decided to share it in this forum now.

Creating your test table:

```
create table #testTable(ID int, Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int)
Insert into #testTable values(1,7,null,12)
Insert into #testTable values(2,2,46,null)
Insert into #testTable values(3,null,null,null)
Insert into #testTable values(4,245,1,792)
```

Finding min value in row data:

```
Select ID, Col1, Col2, Col3 ,(SELECT Min(v) FROM (  VALUES  (Col1), (Col2), (Col3)  ) AS value(v)) [MIN] from #testTable order by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
Select id, Col1, Col2, Col3, least(Col1, Col2, Col3) as MIN From YourTableNameHere
```

Comment: LEAST is not implemented in all databases. I know it is in Oracle and MySQL, but not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

in this way you don't need to check for `nulls`, just use `min` and a `subquery`

```
select tbl.id,tbl.col1,tbl.col2,tbl.col3,
      (select min(t.col) 
      from ( 
            select col1 as col from tbl_name t where t.id=tbl.id
            union all
            select col2 as col from tbl_name t where t.id=tbl.id
            union all
            select col3 as col from tbl_name t where t.id=tbl.id 
           )t) 
from tbl_name tbl
```

*Output:*

```
1   7       NULL    12      7
2   2       46      NULL    2
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   245     1       792     1
```

Comment: I suspect these correlated subqueries will not perform well for the "huge table" the OP has specified.

Comment: Yes, to be honest with you I was writing the solution with using coalesce and case statement but you posted the one before me so I thought to say a different way

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your query with `coalesce()`:

```
Select Id,
       (Case When Col1 <= coalesce(Col2, col3, col1) And
                  Col1 <= coalesce(Col3, col2, col1)
            Then Col1
            When Col2 <= coalesce(Col1, col3, col2) And
                 Col2 <= coalesce(Col3, col1, col2)
            Then Col2 
            Else Col3
        End) As MIN
From YourTableNameHere;
```

This doesn't require inventing a "magic" number or over-complicating the logic.