# How to get Minimum minimum value of a row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, min

I want to get the minimum value of a row in MS SQL like in below table I have minimum value is 4, it will print 4 in output column

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 4 | 5 | 4 |

Answer (score 5):

That was answered here:
[What's the best way to select the minimum value from several columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-minimum-value-from-several-columns)

Using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, MinValue
FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(d) AS MinValue FROM (VALUES (Col1), (Col2), (Col3)) AS a(d)) A
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbbd3/1)

Comment: :) I'm standing on the shoulders of giants!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` and `MIN` as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(x.cols) AS least_ --, MAX(x.cols) AS greatest_
FROM   your_table t
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( t.col1 ), ( t.col2 ), ( t.col3 ), ( t.col4 )) AS x ( cols );
```

Comment: This statement will return the minimum value for the entire table, not for each row.

Comment: Then OP can use the `GROUP BY t.pkcolumn`

Answer (score 0):

Use **CASE** Expression to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE( COL1 INT ,COL2 INT ,COL3 INT )
Insert into @T Values(6,4,5)

SELECT CASE WHEN COL1 < COL2 AND COL1 < COL3 THEN COL1 
            WHEN COL2 < COL1 AND COL2 < COL3 THEN COL2 
            WHEN COL3 < COL1 AND COL3 < COL2 THEN COL3 END 
FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using **nested CASE** expression also as follows:

```
select 
Col1,
Col2,
Col3,
Case 
    When (Col1 > Col2 AND Col1 > Col3 )
        Then Col1
    else 
        Case 
            When (Col2 > Col3)
                Then Col2
            else 
                Col3
        END
END as  Output
from
TableName
```