# Comparison between dates in several columns

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a table where each row has several dates. How can I select the `min` of all the dates in the row?

Existing table:

| Id | Date_1 | Date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021/10/25 | 2021/03/15 |
| 2 | 2021/08/21 | 2021/12/04 |
| 3 | 2021/07/02 | 2021/09/11 |

Expected result:

| Id | Min_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021/03/15 |
| 2 | 2021/08/21 |
| 3 | 2021/07/02 |

Ideally something like:
SELECT Id, least(Date_1, Date_2)
from table

thought that doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean "doesn't work"? If it causes an error, include the error message in your question. If it runs, but doesn't return the desired results, include the results it currently returns in your question.

Comment: You might find this previous question useful, a couple of different ways are suggested, either using `CASE` statements or a `CROSS APPLY`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-minimum-value-from-several-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to select the minimum value from several columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-minimum-value-from-several-columns)