# SQL code to create min date column based on multiple date columns

Tags: sql, min

I have an SQL table with multiple date columns, some of which are blank ([Example of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSoH6.png)) and I want to create a column in SQL that calculates the earliest date across the 3 columns ([Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGtBE.png))

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: And your SQL engine is?

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/29834765/5027339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always mention the db name with version for better solution.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Patients (Patient varchar(50), Doctor_Date date, Nurse_Date date, Physio_Date date);

 insert into Patients (Patient,Doctor_Date)values ('Patient 1','26/11/2021');
 insert into Patients (Patient,Doctor_Date,Nurse_Date,Physio_Date) values('Patient 2','17/11/2021','20/11/2021','16/11/2021');
 insert into Patients (Patient,Nurse_Date,Physio_Date) values('Patient 3','5/12/2021','4/05/2021');
```

Query:

```
  select Patient, 
              (SELECT MIN(mindate) FROM (VALUES (Doctor_Date), (Nurse_Date), (Physio_Date)) AS X(mindate)) AS Minimum_Date
  from Patients
```

Output:

| patient | minimum_date |
| --- | --- |
| Patient 1 | 2021-11-26 |
| Patient 2 | 2021-11-16 |
| Patient 3 | 2021-05-04 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=18dd5fa26cf15d1605f88a5030572318)*