# Join tables of historical and future data sets

Tags: sql

I need to join a historical data set and a forcast data set in two separate tables.
the unique ID is common to both tables.   The dates cross over to f.date start = hdate minus 3 months,

```
\\Historical data as H date ends today()
H data structure
| H.Date | H.Data |H.Unique_ID |

\\Future data as F date begins at today-90 days
F data structure
| F.Date | F.Data |F.Unique_ID |

ideally I would like Desired view to have the following columns
| Date | H.Data | F.Data |F.Unique_ID |
```

is there a way to join these two tables like the above.   Will I need to append the date somehow?

```
select
    case
        when H.date < F.date
        then H.date
        else F.date
    end
    H.date as Date
    H.data
    F.Date
From Historical as H
Left Join on F.Unique_ID = H.Unique_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what server you're using but [most seem to support `LEAST` now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22833781/20564392). If yours does, this is probably easiest:

```sql
select
   least(h.date, f.date)
  ,h.data
  ,f.data
from
  historical h
  left join future f on h.unique_id = f.unique_id
```

You may need to do some management and cleaning (like [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) depending on what your data look like.

> is there a way to join these two tables like the above.

There are many other ways to join them. `LEFT JOIN` with this source gets you all the historical records whether or not there is a matching future record.