# Scalar Max in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to implement the scalar MAX in Sql server (like Math.Max). (In essense I want to implement something like Max(expression, 0), to make negative values replaced by 0.)

I've seen in other threads solutions with

- creating a scalar function *(how's that with performance?)*
- case when expression > 0 THEN expression ELSE 0)  *(then 'expression' is evaluated twice?)*
- complicated uses of
  Max(aggregate).

What's the best?
Why does Sql Server not have something like this built in? Any complications I don't see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989415/t-sql-equivalent-of-excel-max-function-to-return-larger-of-two-numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-net

Comment: In order to get this feature into the product please vote on the Microsoft Connect item: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/767183/t-sql-provide-scalar-min-and-scalar-max

Comment: The feature request has been moved and can be voted on [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32902729-max-min-as-non-aggregate-function)

Comment: Good news! SQL Server 2022 will finally implement [GREATEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest).

Answer (score 6):

In all other major systems this function is called `GREATEST`.

`SQL Server` *seriously* lacks it.

You can make a bunch of case statements, or use something like this:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  MAX(expression)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  expression
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  0
                ) q
        ) AS greatest
FROM    table_that_has_a_field_named_expression
```

The latter one is a trifle less performant than `CASE` statements.

Comment: This is great because if the first expression is a complicated calculation and you're comparing it to a constant, you only have to write the complicated calculation once!

Comment: In order to get this feature into the product please vote on the Microsoft Connect item: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/767183/t-sql-provide-scalar-min-and-scalar-max

Comment: Voted! This would definitely be a useful addition!

Comment: Hi!  Do you know if this has since been added to SQL Server?  I checked the MS Connect link but looks like they closed down Connect.  Thx.

Comment: OK thanks, I checked some more as well, couldn't find anything.  It's too bad because I think other RDBMS's have it.

Comment: The feature request has been moved and can be voted on [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32902729-max-min-as-non-aggregate-function)

Comment: Hello from the future and the past. As of Sql Server 2022 `GREATEST` is supported.

Answer (score 1):

you want to create a user-defined scalar function named MAX in sql server to take two parameters as input, an expression and a min value, and return the expression if it exceeds the min value, otherwise return the min value?

I wouldn't worry about the performance of scalar functions, let the server do that.
I'd also use IF instead of CASE to test for > min value.

SQL server doesn't have a built in function for you because they didn't think it would be widely enough used, I guess.

Comment: about the performance of scalar functions: they can be really painfull, but i think it is safe to assume that as long as there is no table/view logic involved, they should be quite fast (like built in system functions?) – Rein 0 secs ago

Comment: IF and CASE are different statement types. Whether you can use IF over CASE depends on where you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As of Sql Server 2022, the `GREATEST` function is what you're looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current

```sql
SELECT GREATEST(expr1, expr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query optimizer should prevent the expression from being calculated multiple times.

For readability / maintainability, consider using a CTE to calculate the expression before the CASE statement.