# Get MAX and MIN values of each rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a set of rows with values

[image]

I want the following OutPut with individual Max and min values

[image]

Sorry for the poor prntsceen. i dont know how to draw tables in stackoverflow.

Comment: Look at this topic looks like your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097518/sql-selecting-min-value-from-row-data-not-column-data

Comment: that will only return me the max or min values. i want the whole table along with two new columns with max and min value.

Comment: Is there any ID in your table? Maybe you could use [PIVOT][1] to rotate the table and hence to obtain the min and the max values. [1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: no thats the problem i dont have id. the table is actually getting created on the runtime. all i have is rowid via Row_Number() method

Comment: and ya if there is Null in the row the the min value should be NULL

Comment: okay may be replace the NULL with a 0 but it should not be 1 for the first row

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select value1, value2, value3, value4,
       [min]=(select min(value) from (
              select value1 union all
              select value2 union all
              select value3 union all
              select value4) X(value)),
       [max]=(select max(value) from (
              select value1 union all
              select value2 union all
              select value3 union all
              select value4) Y(value))
  from tbl;
```

To recognize NULLs as **min** values, use the below instead

```
select value1, value2, value3, value4,
       [min]=(select TOP(1) value from (
                 select value1 union all
                 select value2 union all
                 select value3 union all
                 select value4) X(value)
              ORDER BY value ASC),
       [max]=(select TOP(1) value from (
                 select value1 union all
                 select value2 union all
                 select value3 union all
                 select value4) X(value)
              ORDER BY value DESC)
  from tbl;
```

Comment: Updated to cater for nulls

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      Value1 INT
    , Value2 INT
    , Value3 INT
    , Value4 INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4)
VALUES 
    (NULL, 1, 1, NULL),
    (NULL, 1, 2, NULL),
    (NULL, 2, 2, NULL),
    (NULL, 2, 2, NULL),
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1, 2),
    (1, 1, 1, NULL),
    (2, 2, 3, 2),
    (2, 2, 2, 2),
    (1, 1, 1, 1)

SELECT
      Value1
    , Value2
    , Value3
    , Value4
    , MinValue = (
        SELECT TOP 1 value 
        FROM (
            SELECT value = value1
              UNION
            SELECT value2
              UNION
            SELECT value3
              UNION
            SELECT value4
        ) mn
        ORDER BY value
    )
    , MaxValue = (
        SELECT MAX(value) 
        FROM (
            SELECT value = value1
              UNION
            SELECT value2
              UNION
            SELECT value3
              UNION
            SELECT value4
        ) mx
    )
FROM @temp
```

Results window:

[image: proff]

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
declare @T table
(
  id int, 
  num1 int, 
  num2 int, 
  num3 int,  
  num4 int,   
  num5 int
)

insert into @T values
(1,     6,      51,      NULL,      99,      34),
(2,     222,    251,     24,     299,     234),
(3,     NULL,   NULL,    NULL,   NULL,    NULL)

select * From @T

SELECT id,
(SELECT 
(CASE WHEN (num1+num2+num3+num4+num5) IS NULL THEN NULL 
    ELSE MIN(v) end) 
FROM (VALUES (num1), 
            (num2), 
            (num3), 
            (num4), 
            (num5)) AS value(v)) as [MinVal],
(SELECT MAX(v) 
FROM (VALUES (num1), 
            (num2), 
            (num3), 
            (num4), 
            (num5)) AS value(v)) as [MaxVal]
FROM @T
```