# How to get the minimum value in a set of columns while excluding a certain value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying a query to select the minimum value in a row but also exclude a certain value (-998).

The table looks like this:

```
col1        col2         col3
----------------------------------
1            1          -998
2           -998        2
3            2          1
-998         1          3
```

So in the first row, the minimum value would be 1; in the second row, it would be 2; and in the third row, it would be 1 again.

I tried using a case statement and excluding -998 in each condition, but it keeps grabbing -998 for some reason.

```
SELECT  
    CASE
        WHERE (col1 &lt;= col2 and col1 &lt;= col3) and col1 != -998 THEN col1
        WHERE (col2 &lt;= col1 and col2 &lt;= col3) and col2 != -998 THEN col2
        WHERE (col3 &lt;= col1 and col3 &lt;= col2) and col3 != -998 THEN col3
    END AS [MIN_VAL]
FROM myTable
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would ge awesome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get MAX and MIN values of each rows in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166225/get-max-and-min-values-of-each-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: I did not understand how the minimum value in col2 is '2'.  It should be 1 right? Can u pls explain!

Comment: Since we are excluding -998 the only values in row 2 are 2 and 2 so it should be 2

Comment: Ya! now I understand good question!

Answer (score 5):

Use the [table value constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) to unpivot your column values and exclude values from there.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0057/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  col3 int
);


insert into YourTable values
(1    ,        1   ,       -998),
(2    ,       -998 ,       2   ),
(3    ,        2   ,       1   ),
(-998 ,        1   ,       3   );
```

**Query 1**:

```
select (
       select min(R.Value)
       from (values(T.col1),
                   (T.col2), 
                   (T.col3)) as R(Value)
       where R.Value <> -998
       ) as min_val
from YourTable as T;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0057/1/0)**:

```
| MIN_VAL |
|---------|
|       1 |
|       2 |
|       1 |
|       1 |
```

Comment: Nice! I've never tried using table value constructor. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
use tempdb

create table myTable(
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int
)
insert into myTable values
(1, 1, -998),
(2, -998, 2),
(3, 2, 1),
(-998, 1, 3)

;with cte as(
    select
        rn = row_number() over(order by (select null)),
        col = col1
    from myTable
    union all
    select
        rn = row_number() over(order by (select null)),
        col = col2
    from myTable
    union all
    select
        rn = row_number() over(order by (select null)),
        col = col3
    from myTable
)
select
    minimum = min(col) 
from cte
where col <> - 998
group by rn

drop table mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     CASE
         WHEN (col1 <= col2 or col2 = -998)
              and (col1 <= col3 or col3 = -998)
              and col1 != -998 
         THEN col1
         WHEN (col2 <= col1 or col1 = -998)
              and (col2 <= col3 or col3 = -998)
              and col2 != -998 
         THEN col2
         WHEN (col3 <= col1 or col1 = -998)
              and (col3 <= col2 or col2 = -998)
              and col3 != -998 
         THEN col3
     END AS [MIN_VAL]
FROM myTable;
```