# How to get min/max of two integers in Postgres/SQL?

Tags: postgresql

How do I find the maximum (or minimum) of two integers in Postgres/SQL? One of the integers is not a column value.

I will give an example scenario:

I would like to subtract an integer from a column (in all rows), but the result should not be less than zero. So, to begin with, I have:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = my_column - 10;
```

But this can make some of the values negative. What I would like (in pseudo code) is:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = MAXIMUM(my_column - 10, 0);
```

Comment: Relatedly you can create a union data set and then max that, in sql-server at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne

Answer (score 498, accepted):

Have a look at [GREATEST and LEAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST).

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = GREATEST(my_column - 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 22):

You want the inline sql `case`:

```
set my_column = case when my_column - 10 > 0 then my_column - 10 else 0 end
```

`max()` is an aggregate function and gets the maximum of a row of a result set.

Edit: oops, didn't know about `greatest` and `least` in postgres.  Use that instead.

Comment: This version is useful if you're restricted to standard SQL.