# ORDER BY different columns in same priority

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 date columns:

`create_date` and `modify_date`.
`create_date` is always set and `modify_date` sometimes.

Now I want to order my query by both of them with the same priority.

If I do this:

```
order by create_date desc, modify_date desc
```

I first get all rows sorted by `create_date` and then by `modify_date` but I want the rows sorted by both in the same priority. I need this:

```
create_date  |  modify_date
2011-12-31   |  -
2011-12-01   |  2011-12-30
2011-12-29   |  -
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select *
from yourtable
order by coalesce(modify_date, create_date) desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to order by `modify_date`, and if `modify_date` is `NULL`, it will use the `create_date` value:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(modify_date, create_date) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The column naming implies that modify_date is either not set or higher then creation date, so the other answers will work. If not, you may use a user defined function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne) (adjust to use Dates instead of int). Then use

```
ORDER BY dbo.HigherArgument(create_date, modify_date) DESC
```