# Better Min/Max Function for Dates in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I created the following function to determine the MAX date between two dates. It takes roughly from 00.030 to 00.050 seconds to run one of the SELECT statements in the function's comment.

Is there a better performing and cleaner way?

```
/* Returns the greater of two dates.

    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate(NULL      , NULL)
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', NULL)
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate(NULL      , '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/2/2011', '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', '1/2/2011')

*/
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnMaxDate 
(
    @Date1 DATETIME,
    @Date2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result DATETIME

    IF @Date1 IS NULL AND @Date2 IS NULL

        SET @Result = NULL;

    ELSE IF @Date1 IS NULL

        SET @Result = @Date2

    ELSE IF @Date2 IS NULL

        SET @Result = @Date1

    ELSE
        IF @Date1 >= @Date2

            SET @Result = @Date1

        ELSE

            SET @Result = @Date2

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Max function in SQL Server that takes two values like Math.Max in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne)

Comment: @MarcB - the duplicate you refer to has nothing to do with performance. OP is not asking **for** a function, he is asking on how to improve performance of **this** function.

Comment: @MikeTeeVee, huh? See the first comment and no (see comment #2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnMaxDate 
(
    @Date1 DATETIME,
    @Date2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN
        CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(@Date1, @Date2) > ISNULL(@Date2, @Date1)
            THEN ISNULL(@Date1, @Date2)
            ELSE ISNULL(@Date2, @Date1)
        END
END
```

Comment: Although this version is written cleaner and nicely avoids the use of the @Result variable, it does not perform any faster.

Comment: >>it does not perform any faster<< The performance increase is roughly 0.002ms.

Answer (score 2):

I found that a `case` structure runs about three times faster than a function call.

```
declare @d table(d1 date, d2 date);
insert into @d values(null,null)
, ('2/19/2012',null)
, (null,'2/19/2012')
, ('2/1/2012','2/15/2012')
, ('2/1/2012','1/15/2012');


declare @md date
, @i int=1
, @ts datetime2
, @ms1 int
, @ms2 int;

-- function
select @ts=GETDATE();
while @i<10000 begin select @md=dbo.fnMaxDate(d1,d2) from @d; set @i+=1; end
select @ms1=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE());

-- recommended case structure
set @i=1;
select @ts=GETDATE();
while @i<10000 begin select @md=case when ISNULL(d1,d2)<ISNULL(d2,d1) then ISNULL(d2,d1) else ISNULL(d1,d2) end from @d; set @i+=1; end
select @ms2=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE());
select [Function Run Time (ms)]=@ms1, [Case Run Time (ms)]=@ms2
go
```

Result:

```
Function Run Time (ms) Case Run Time (ms)
---------------------- ------------------
940                    296
```

Comment: Interesting. I love the timing code, but I do what to use a function. I am trying to clean up a 173KB stored procedure that takes 12 seconds to execute.

Comment: You could replace the function body with the case statement, but you would then have the overhead of calling a function from the sproc.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /* Returns the greater of two dates.

        SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate(NULL      , NULL)
        SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', NULL)
        SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate(NULL      , '1/1/2011')
        SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', '1/1/2011')
        SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/2/2011', '1/1/2011')
        SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', '1/2/2011')

    */
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnMaxDate 
(
    @Date1 DATETIME,
    @Date2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @Result datetime

   SELECT TOP 1 @Result =  T.DateValue
   FROM
     (
     SELECT @Date1 DateValue
     UNION ALL
     SELECT @Date2 DateValue
     ) T
   ORDER BY
     T.DateValue DESC

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, and already answered, but seeing as there was already a test script I couldn't resist having a go :)

I've created a scalar function that outperforms all the other function tests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383012/893766), and a table valued function that is even faster than the scalar UDF.

### Comparable Result (to AMissico's test)

```
TVF = 0.022253313291
SVF = 0.04627526226
```

### The Functions

```sql
/* Returns the greater of two dates.

    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate(NULL      , NULL)
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', NULL)
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate(NULL      , '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/2/2011', '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', '1/2/2011')

*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.svfMaxDate 
(
    @Date1 DATETIME,
    @Date2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN coalesce(dateadd(dd, ((datediff(dd, 0, @Date1) + datediff(dd, 0, @Date2)) + abs(datediff(dd, 0, @Date1) - datediff(dd, 0, @Date2))) / 2, 0), @Date1, @Date2)

END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvfMaxDate
(
    @Date1 DATETIME,
    @Date2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

    RETURN SELECT [MaxDate] = coalesce(dateadd(dd, ((datediff(dd, 0, @Date1) + datediff(dd, 0, @Date2)) + abs(datediff(dd, 0, @Date1) - datediff(dd, 0, @Date2))) / 2, 0), @Date1, @Date2)
    ;
GO
```

I also used AMissico's simple test script to test this, but only bothered to test my version of the functions and the CASE statement to be used as a reference point/baseline:

### Results of Test

```
Case(ms)    svfMaxDate  tvfMaxDate
0.01343000  0.03907000  0.01837000
```

### Normalise Test Results to AMissico's Baseline

```
Baseline Case(ms) / This Test Case(ms) = Normalisation Factor
0.01616 / 0.01334000 = 1.21139430

svfMaxDate * Normalisation Factor= Comparable Result
0.03820000 * 1.21139430 = 0.04627526226

tvfMaxDate * Normalisation Factor= Comparable Result
0.01837 * 1.21139430 = 0.022253313291
```

### Test Script

```sql
declare @d table(d1 date, d2 date); 
insert into @d values(null,null) 
, ('2/19/2012',null) 
, (null,'2/19/2012') 
, ('2/1/2012','2/15/2012') 
, ('2/1/2012','1/15/2012'); 


declare @md date 
, @i int=1 
, @ts datetime2 
, @ms0 int 
, @ms1 int 
, @ms2 int 
;

-- case structure 
set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md=case when ISNULL(d1,d2)<ISNULL(d2,d1) then ISNULL(d2,d1) else ISNULL(d1,d2) end from @d; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms0=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

-- svfMaxDate, Arithmetic
set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md=dbo.svfMaxDate(d1,d2) from @d; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms1=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

-- tvfMaxDate, Arithmetic in TVF with CROSS APPLY
set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md = tf.MaxDate from @d cross apply dbo.tvfMaxDate(d1,d2) as tf; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms2=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

select [Case(ms)]=@ms0/100000.0, fnMaxDate=@ms1/100000.0, tvfMaxDate=@ms2/100000.0
go
```

The TVF credit goes to Jeff Moden, the following link was used as a reference for building it: [How to Make Scalar UDFs Run Faster (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my simple performance testing, I am going with a slightly modified version of my original function (see below).

```
                     IS NULL    CASE        IS NOT NULL  UNION
Case(ms)  Empty Func fnMaxDate1 fnMaxDate2  fnMaxDate3   fnMaxDate4
0.01616   0.0446     0.0518     0.04934     0.05036      0.06177
```

The fastest function method is the CASE statement, but only by approx. 0.003ms The slowest function is the one that uses SELECT UNION by "Pittsburgh DBA". I changed the order of my function to test for the most common result first, which would test both arguments as IS NOT NULL. This change in logic place the performance on par with the CASE function.

Therefore, I am giving up the 0.001ms performance for clarity of the IS NOT NULL function (see below).

Using the following script:

```
declare @d table(d1 date, d2 date); 
insert into @d values(null,null) 
, ('2/19/2012',null) 
, (null,'2/19/2012') 
, ('2/1/2012','2/15/2012') 
, ('2/1/2012','1/15/2012'); 


declare @md date 
, @i int=1 
, @ts datetime2 
, @ms0 int 
, @ms1 int 
, @ms3 int 
, @ms2 int 
, @ms4 int 
, @ms5 int 
;

-- case structure 

set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md=case when ISNULL(d1,d2)<ISNULL(d2,d1) then ISNULL(d2,d1) else ISNULL(d1,d2) end from @d; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms0=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

-- fnMaxDate1, IF IS NULL
set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md=dbo.fnMaxDate1(d1,d2) from @d; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms1=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

-- fnMaxDate2, CASE
set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md=dbo.fnMaxDate2(d1,d2) from @d; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms2=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

-- fnMaxDate3, IF IS NOT NULL
set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md=dbo.fnMaxDate3(d1,d2) from @d; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms3=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

-- fnMaxDate4, SELECT UNION
set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md=dbo.fnMaxDate4(d1,d2) from @d; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms4=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

-- fnMaxDate5, empty function call
set @i=1; 
select @ts=GETDATE(); 
while @i<100000 begin select @md=dbo.fnMaxDate5(d1,d2) from @d; set @i+=1; end 
select @ms5=DATEDIFF(ms,@ts,GETDATE()); 

select [Case(ms)]=@ms0/100000.0, [fnMaxDate5 (empty function call)]=@ms5/100000.0, fnMaxDate1=@ms1/100000.0, fnMaxDate2=@ms2/100000.0, fnMaxDate3 = @ms3/100000.0, fnMaxDate4=@ms4/100000.0
go
```

---

Lastly, here is the final version of the function:

```
/* Returns the greater of two dates.

    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate(NULL      , NULL)
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', NULL)
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate(NULL      , '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/2/2011', '1/1/2011')
    SELECT dbo.fnMaxDate('1/1/2011', '1/2/2011')

*/
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnMaxDate] 
(
    @Date1 DATETIME,
    @Date2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result DATETIME

    IF @Date1 IS NOT NULL AND @Date2 IS NOT NULL

        IF @Date1 >= @Date2

            SET @Result = @Date1

        ELSE

            SET @Result = @Date2

    ELSE IF @Date1 IS NULL

        SET @Result = @Date2

    ELSE IF @Date2 IS NULL

        SET @Result = @Date1

    RETURN @Result

END
```