# Cap field value in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to cap particular fields so that they don't exceed a particular value.

For example, something like this would suffice, where I can specify that a field should not exceed 8:

```
SELECT (
        cap(t.MondayHrs,8) 
        + cap(t.TuesdayHrs,8)
        + cap(t.WednesdayHrs,8)
        + cap(t.ThursdayHrs,8)
        + cap(t.FridayHrs,8)
       ) as TotalHours
```

If MondayHrs = 7, then it should be added to TotalHours as 7.
If MondayHrs = 10, then it should be added to TotalHours as 8 (my capped value)

Is there anything built into T-SQL that could facilitate this?

Comment: Heve you considered using CASE as in CASE WHEN t.MondayHrs < 8 THEN t.MondayHrs ELSE 8 END + CASE WHEN t.TuesdayHrs < 8 THEN t.TuesdayHrs ELSE 8 END + ......

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne)  might help you..  Though you're more looking for a `min` function.

Comment: @SteveFord, I did, but it looked extremely messy.

Comment: User defined function looks good, I will look into it, thanks @MikeChristensen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create function Cap (@Value float,@maxValue float) Returns float 
as
begin
Declare @Result float
if @Value > @maxValue select @Result=@Maxvalue else select @Result=@Value
Return @Result
end;
```

usage

```
Select dbo.Cap(1,10),dbo.Cap(11,10)
```

Comment: This is the path I went down, except I used the UDF from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/124474/324817

Answer (score 6):

Try...

```
select least(t.MondayHrs,8) 
    + least(t.TuesdayHrs,8)
    + least(t.WednesdayHrs,8)
    + least(t.ThursdayHrs,8)
    + least(t.FridayHrs,8)
   ) as TotalHours
```

Comment: most elegant solution! and not using GREATEST like @juergen-d suggested which actually does the opposite of what joshschreuder wants to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate idea would be to use CASE. For example:

```
SELECT ( 
       (CASE WHEN t.MondayHrs > 8 THEN 8 ELSE t.MondayHrs END)
       + (CASE WHEN t.TuesdayHrs > 8 THEN 8 ELSE t.TuesdayHrs END)
) as TotalHours
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function for that like MySQL [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

Then you could do something like

```
select greatest(some_col, 8) +
       greatest(other_col, 8) + 
       ...
from your_table
```