# Returning largest value across columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008, I need to query across columns in T-SQL and return the largest number I find (example below using dates, but same idea applies to numbers). "NULL" indicates a null value, not the literal word (sorry if I'm being captain obvious). The column "DesiredResultColumn" shows the final result I want from searching across Column1 through Column3. I'm not finding an example on here which fits this exactly.

---

```
    ID       Column1    Column2     Column3        DesiredResultColumn
    001      1/1/2010   5/7/2011    8/12/2008      5/7/2011
    002      7/1/2014   7/3/2012    10/12/2013     7/1/2014
    003      9/1/2012   12/7/2012   NULL           12/7/2012
    004      11/1/2012  NULL        8/12/2013      8/12/2013
```

---

Unfortunately my tables, due to the source system constraints, aren't normalized, otherwise a max function would solve my problem. Thoughts? I appreciate it!

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: The last column, DesiredResultColumn, is the desired final result. I'll clarify that in the question, thanks.

Comment: Do a UDF like http://stackoverflow.com/a/124474/961695

Comment: you can probably use a `case` condition along with `ISNULL()` to get the result.

Comment: Try Sven's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns/6871572#6871572

Comment: I just now found that, @AHiggins - that's exactly what I needed. You rock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871572/1270504):

```
SELECT tbl.ID,
       (SELECT MAX(Date)
        FROM (VALUES (tbl.Column1), (tbl.Column2), (tbl.Column3)) AS AllDates(Date)) AS DesiredResultColumn
FROM tbl
```

Of course, that only works on SQL 2008 and above, but you said you have 2008 so it should be fine.

The nice thing about this over use of a `CASE` or similar expression is, for one, how it's a bit shorter and, in my opinion, easier to read. But also, it handles `NULL` values so you don't really have to think about them.

Comment: Perfect, Matthew. Thank you. It is the same as Sven's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns/6871572#6871572.  The good thing about this one also is that it's easy to reference many joined tables in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use a `case` condition along with `ISNULL()` to get the result like below ( a sample, didn't included nullity check using `ISNULL()`. You can include that)

```
select ID,
       Column1,
       Column2,
       Column3,
       case when Column1 > Column2 and Column1 > Column3 then Column1 
            when Column2 > Column1 and Column2 > Column3 then Column2
            else column3 end as DesiredResultColumn
from your_table
```

Comment: @M.Ali, It would be since I haven't checked for `NULL` and ID 3 have `NULL` for one of the column and that has been clearly mentioned in my answer, think you missed it.

Answer (score 0):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID VARCHAR(10), Column1 DATE, Column2 DATE, Column3 DATE)       

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('001','1/1/2010','5/7/2011','8/12/2008'),      
('002','7/1/2014','7/3/2012','10/12/2013'),     
('003','9/1/2012','12/7/2012',   NULL    ),    
('004','11/1/2012',   NULL   ,'8/12/2013')
```

### Query

```
;WITH CTE
AS (    
    SELECT *
    FROM @TABLE 
    UNPIVOT ( Dates FOR ColumnName IN (Column1, Column2,Column3) )up
   )
SELECT t.ID , t.Column1, t.Column2, t.Column3, MAX(Dates) Highest_Date
FROM @TABLE t LEFT JOIN CTE C
ON t.ID = c.ID
GROUP BY t.ID , t.Column1, t.Column2, t.Column3
```

### Result

```
╔═════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ ID  ║  Column1   ║  Column2   ║  Column3   ║ Highest_Date ║
╠═════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 001 ║ 2010-01-01 ║ 2011-05-07 ║ 2008-08-12 ║ 2011-05-07   ║
║ 002 ║ 2014-07-01 ║ 2012-07-03 ║ 2013-10-12 ║ 2014-07-01   ║
║ 003 ║ 2012-09-01 ║ 2012-12-07 ║ NULL       ║ 2012-12-07   ║
║ 004 ║ 2012-11-01 ║ NULL       ║ 2013-08-12 ║ 2013-08-12   ║
╚═════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbc73/2)