# Math calculating min or max for more than two columns

Tags: math, sql-server-2008-r2

I found this on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne) by splattne, but couldn't post a comment asking the following question, so here it is.

```
-- the following expression calculates ==> max(@val1, @val2)
SELECT 0.5 * ((@val1 + @val2) + ABS(@val1 - @val2))
```

What would this formula look like to get the minimum?

What would this formula look like for 4 columns?  (I know, more than one question.)

Answer (score 1):

```
-- the following expression calculates ==> min(@val1, @val2)
SELECT 0.5 * ((@val1 + @val2) - ABS(@val1 - @val2))
```

for multi column, you might just want to create a function.
depending on if you have fixed number of columns or variable number of columns to find minimum, you will have to create different approach for creating such function.

Comment: I just have a fixed number of columns (4) that I am dealing with, but lots of records, so I don't really want to use a function for performance reasons.

Comment: ok then you will be putting same code you put in your function in the query. dont think it will be any performance problem for scalar function. i am assuming you know how to check for max of for values. a case statement should do.

Comment: you can also use [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6871572/3754372)  to get min but it may be slower then case statements.