# SQL between min of two values

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

If I have to write this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE data BETWEEN interval1 AND interval2
```

- `interval1` is `fld1` if `fld1` >= '2014-1-1' otherwise it's '2014-1-1'
- `interval2` is `fld2` if `fld2` is <= '2014-12-31' otherwise it's '2014-12-31'

How can I write it without using variables?

i try

```
Ksdt_TP022_Data BETWEEN     
                         (SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN sdt_TP019_InizioVal < '2014-1-1' THEN '2014-1-1' 
                                ELSE sdt_TP019_InizioVal 
                                END as b
                        from TP022_Quarto)
                         AND 
                         (SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN sdt_TP019_Fineval > '2014-12-31' THEN '2014-12-31' 
                                WHEN sdt_TP019_Fineval IS NULL THEN '2014-12-31' 
                                ELSE sdt_TP019_Fineval 
                                END as a
                            from TP022_Quarto)
```

but get compiler error

Comment: Which SQL Server version? If you have 2012 or above, you can use IIF(), ie, WHERE data BETWEEN IIF(fld1 >= '2014-1-1', fld1, '2014-1-1')

Comment: i have only only 2008 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  Table1 
WHERE
  data BETWEEN interval1 AND coalesce(interval2, '2014-12-31')
  and data between '2014-1-1' and '2014-12-31'
```

Comment: i try it before but interval2 can be null and in that case i have to take '2014-12-31'

Comment: @Madhivanan with coalesce works too, but this way it's more nice ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select * from Table1 
WHERE data between 
case when fld1 < '20140101' then '20140101' else fld1 end and 
case when fld2 >'20141231 then '20141231' else fld2 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne)

In short, you could use a UDF (user defined function) or CASE statements.