# Syntax of MS Access/SQL sub-query including aggregate functions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to produce a database to manage maintenance of equipment. I have two tables:

1. One (*Inventory*) containing details of each piece of equipment, including *Purchase Date* and *Service Period*,
2. One containing details of work done (*WorkDone*), including the date the work was carried out (*Work Date*).

I would like a query that displays the date that it should be next serviced. So far I have:

```
SELECT Max(DateAdd('m', [Inventory].[Service Period], 
                        [WorkDone].[Work Date])) AS NextServiceDate, 
       Inventory.Equipement
FROM Inventory INNER JOIN WorkDone ON Inventory.ID = WorkDone.Equipment
GROUP BY Inventory.Equipement
```

This works well as long as some work done has been registered for a given piece of equipment. If no work has been carried out I would like the *NextServiceDat*e to also show

```
DateAdd('m',[Inventory].[Service Period], [Inventory].[Purchase Date])
```

However, I cannot work out how to get SQL/MS access to compare two values and only display the greater of the two. From reading around I think I should be able to do a sub-query, but I cannot work out how to phase it.

I've been trying to adapt @MikeTeeVee's answer from here: [Is there a Max function in SQL Server that takes two values like Math.Max in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne). But I keep getting errors saying that query is not part of an aggregate function and I'm not certain what I doing wrong. For example, I tried:

```
SELECT Inventory.Equipement,
       (SELECT MAX(NSD_proxy) 
        FROM (VALUES 
             (Max(DateAdd('m', Inventory.[Service Period], WorkDone.[Work Date]))), 
                 (DateAdd('m', Inventory.[Service Period], Inventory.[Purchase Date]))) 
         AS FUNCTION(NSD_proxy)
        ) AS NextServiceDate,
FROM Inventory INNER JOIN WorkDone ON Inventory.ID = WorkDone.Equipment
GROUP BY Inventory.Equipement
```

which has some syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a `LEFT JOIN` to return matched or unmatched records where latter is filled with NULLs, and then run your aggregate, `MAX`, with an [NZ()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c):

```
SELECT Max(NZ(DateAdd('m', i.[Service Period], w.[Work Date]),
              DateAdd('m', i.[Service Period], i.[Purchase Date]))
          ) AS NextServiceDate, i.Equipement
FROM Inventory i LEFT JOIN WorkDone w ON i.ID = w.Equipment
GROUP BY i.Equipement
```

Comment: Edit: Actually I have a further question as I would not like to apply a criteria: I would like to return all entries where NextServiceDate is earlier than a weeks time. I have tried: `HAVING Max(NZ(DateAdd('m', i.[Service Period], w.[Work Date]), DateAdd('m', i.[Service Period], i.[Purchase Date]))) < DateAdd('ww',1,Date())` but this only compares the Day part of the date. So for example today is the 31/3/18 so it's showing all entries that have a NextServiceDate in the first 6 days of any month. (I have a UK system so the date format is dd/mm/yyyy just in case that effects things).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to compare the two dates, just check if a `WorkDone` record exists to match the `Inventory` record.

You can use:

```
IIF(ISNULL(WorkDone.Equipment),
DateAdd('m',[Inventory].[Service Period],[Inventory].[Purchase Date]),
Max(DateAdd('m',[Inventory].[Service Period],[WorkDone].[Work Date])))
AS NextServiceDate
```

The rest of your query can remain as is.

Comment: This gives me an error saying: "Your query does not include the specified expression 'IIF(ISNULL(WorkDone.Equipment), DateAdd('m',[Inventory].[Service Period],[Inventory].[Purchase Date]), Max(DateAdd('m',[Inventory].[Service Period],[WorkDone].[Work Date])))' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: Just use `MAX(IIF(...)) AS.NextServiceDate`