# SQL Server 2017 Replacing Negative value without repeating long expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, sql-server-2017

I have a long expression which may return a positive, negative or zero decimal value.  I would like to do this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN {long expression} < 0 THEN 0 ELSE {long expression} END
```

But I don't want to repeat the long expression.  I would like something like ISNULL, such as

```
SELECT ISNEGATIVE({long expression}, 0)
```

But that doesn't seem to be a thing.  Obviously GREATER would work but it's 2017.

I'm pretty sure I'm hosed, but was hoping for a miracle.  Anyone?

Comment: Do any of the answers to [Is there a Max function in SQL Server that takes two values like Math.Max in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/124417/1115360) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CTE could be a good fit here. Something like:

```sql
with cte as (
  select *,
     longExpression = «long expression definition here»
  from yourTable
)
select «other stuff»,
   CASE WHEN longExpression < 0 THEN 0 ELSE longExpression END
from cte;
```

Comment: Probably the most elegant workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `CROSS APPLY`.  They will allow you to reference aliases and stack calculations

```
 Select CASE WHEN AVAL < 0 THEN 0 ELSE AVAL END
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (longexpression) )B(AVAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for some variety...

You *could* round trip it through `FORMAT` as this allows positive values, negative values and zeroes to be [treated differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

```
SELECT CAST(FORMAT({long expression}, '#.########;\0;0') AS DECIMAL(18,8))
```

I'd just use the `APPLY` myself though as first port of call (rather than gratuitously calling a known slow function unnecessarily with some completely unwarranted string casting).

Comment: I ALWAYS forget about format option !

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - In this case probably best forgotten about anyway 

Comment: I support format() provided it is used sparingly.  :)   It is just another tool in the belt.

Comment: yeah - if it is being applied to a number of rows that are fit for human consumption (i.e. a small number) then it is plenty fast enough. Generally that is when you would expect `FORMAT` to be used. The case in this question has no such guarantees though.