# VBA SQL syntax fix selection

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

please help me with this code. I dont know any VBA and am barely familiar with SQL.
This is the DB at the company Im working.
I want to change the INSERT with SELECTED values:
I want to use this logic:

```
Max(stdsneedaccomnowfut.ArrDate,stdsneedaccomnowfut.startpaymcycle) AS NPCStartDate
Min(stdsneedaccomnowfut.DepDate,stdsneedaccomnowfut.endpaymcycle) AS NPCEndDate
```

I want to replace the current `as NPCStartDate` and `as NPCEndDate` with the logic above,
But I keep getting or syntax errors or others, or the line is too long and there are problems with concatenation.

here is the full code for Event Procedure:

```
Private Sub HFID_AfterUpdate()
' Disable warning messages
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

' Check if the current date is between two specific dates
If DateDiff("d", #6/16/2024#, Now()) < 0 And DateDiff("d", #8/24/2018#, Now()) > 0 Then
    ' Delete all records from the "LSCase" table
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM LSCase"
    txtdate.SetFocus
    
    ' Exit the subprocedure if the "txtdate" control is null
    If IsNull(txtdate) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Calculate a new invoice number
    intinvoiceno = DMax("InvoiceNo", "tblpaymentlog") + 1
    
    ' Insert records into "LSCase" table based on a complex SELECT query
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO LSCase (studID, HFFirstName, HFSurname, studFirstName, acctype, HFID, accrateLS, accrateHS, PL, PLrate, ArrDate, DepDate, NPCStartDate, NPCStartWkday, NPCStartwk, NPCEndDate, NPCEndWkday, NPCEndwk, NPCEndDateFinal, Nights, TotalRate, DailyRate, TotalPay, InvoiceNo, HSRate)" _
        & " SELECT stdsneedaccomnowfut.studID, stdsneedaccomnowfut.HFFirstName, stdsneedaccomnowfut.HFSurname, stdsneedaccomnowfut.studFirstName, stdsneedaccomnowfut.acctype, stdsneedaccomnowfut.HFID, stdsneedaccomnowfut.accrateLS, stdsneedaccomnowfut.accrateHS, stdsneedaccomnowfut.PL, " _
        & " stdsneedaccomnowfut.PLrate, stdsneedaccomnowfut.ArrDate, stdsneedaccomnowfut.DepDate, IIf(DCount('*', 'tblpaymentlog', 'studID=' & [stdsneedaccomnowfut]![studID])=0, [stdsneedaccomnowfut]![ArrDate], #" & HFID & "#-7) AS NPCStartDate, WeekdayName(Weekday([NPCStartDate],0)) AS NPCStartWkday, " _
        & " wkk(#" & HFID & "#)-1 AS NPCStartwk, #" & HFID & "# AS NPCEndDate, WeekdayName(Weekday([NPCEndDate],0)) AS NPCEndWkday, wkk(#" & HFID & "#) AS NPCEndwk, #" & HFID & "#  AS NPCEndDateFinal, -DateDiff('d',[NPCEndDate]," _
        & "[NPCStartDate]) AS Nights, tblHFrates.hfos AS TotalRate, [TotalRate]/7 AS DailyRate, [TotalRate]*IIf(DateDiff('d', IIf([DepDate] > [NPCEndDate], [DepDate], [NPCEndDate]), IIf([ArrDate] > [NPCStartDate], [ArrDate], [NPCStartDate])) > 0, DateDiff('d', IIf([ArrDate] > [NPCStartDate], [ArrDate], [NPCStartDate]), IIf([DepDate] > [NPCEndDate], [NPCEndDate], [DepDate])), 0) + [PLrate] AS TotalPay, DCount('studID', 'stdsneedaccomnowfut', 'studID<' & [studID])+" & intinvoiceno & " AS Expr1, tblHFrates.HFOS FROM stdsneedaccomnowfut INNER JOIN tblHFrates ON stdsneedaccomnowfut.acctype = tblHFrates.Type ORDER BY stdsneedaccomnowfut.studID;"
    
    ' Update the "LSCase" table with date information
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE LSCase SET LSCase.Dateadded = #" & HFID & "#, LSCase.PayDate = #" & txtdate & "#;"
    
    ' Delete records from "tblpaymentlog" based on the "Dateadded" field
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblpaymentlog WHERE Dateadded = #" & Me.HFID & "#"
    
    ' Delete records from "LSCase" where the difference between "NPCStartDate" and "ArrDate" is greater than or equal to 7
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM LSCase WHERE DateDiff('d', [NPCStartDate], [ArrDate]) >= 7;"
    
    ' Update the "LSCase" table with the correct number of nights based on the new logic
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE LSCase SET LSCase.Nights = -DateDiff('d', IIf([DepDate] < [NPCEndDate], [DepDate], [NPCEndDate]), IIf([ArrDate] > [NPCStartDate], [ArrDate], [NPCStartDate]));"

    ' Update the "LSCase" table with arrival and departure dates from another table
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE LSCase INNER JOIN tblstudentsallocatedlocal ON LSCase.studID = tblstudentsallocatedlocal.studID SET LSCase.ArrDate = [tblstudentsallocatedlocal]![ArrDate], LSCase.DepDate = [tblstudentsallocatedlocal]![DepDate];"
    
    ' Re-enable warning messages
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
    ' Update the source object of the subform and make certain controls visible
    Me.sfrmweeklypaymentcalc.SourceObject = "LS"
    Detail.Visible = True
    sfrmweeklypaymentcalc.SetFocus
    
    ' Exit the subprocedure
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The desired result would be if you could help to implement the logic I mentioned at the beginning to the code above

Comment: "I dont know any VBA and am barely familiar with SQL" - Not a great start.

Comment: I suggest adding a variable named strSQL that you populate and use in your DoCmd.RunSQL calls. It will make it easier to isolate the SQL statement and try it outside your code. Will also make your code easier to read.

Comment: You need a [GROUP BY clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/group-by-clause-microsoft-access-sql). Since we don't know the table schema and don't know by what you want to group, it is difficult to give you an answer. Basically, everything which is not grouped-by must be selected with an aggregate function (like Min or Max).

Comment: Also **parameterize your queries**. What you have so far is dangerous, it's subject to injection attacks as well as syntax errors.

Comment: here is a trick for getting max of 2 values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne

Comment: Use DMin and DMax domain aggregate functions to pull these values into variables then feed them into the SQL statement with concatenation or parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access. Same for the DCount. SQL would be shorter and easier to read if you did not prefix every field with table name.

Comment: Correction, cannot do that for the DCount. Why save aggregate data when it can be calculated when needed? Domain aggregate functions in SQL can cause slow performance.