# Selecting most recent date between two columns

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

If I have a table that (among other columns) has two DATETIME columns, how would I select the **most recent** date from those two columns.

Example:

```
ID     Date1     Date2

1      1/1/2008   2/1/2008

2      2/1/2008   1/1/2008

3      1/10/2008  1/10/2008
```

If I wanted my results to look like

```
ID     MostRecentDate

1      2/1/2008

2      2/1/2008

3      1/10/2008
```

Is there a simple way of doing this that I am obviously overlooking? I know I can do subqueries and case statements or even write a function in sql server to handle it, but I had it in my head that there was a max-compare type function already built in that I am just forgetting about.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

CASE is IMHO your best option:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN Date1 > Date2 THEN Date1
            ELSE Date2
       END AS MostRecentDate
FROM Table
```

---

If one of the columns is nullable just need to enclose in [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql):

```
.. COALESCE(Date1, '1/1/1973') > COALESCE(Date2, '1/1/1973')
```

Comment: I figured that was the case. I was almost certain that there was a date comparison function already built where I could have just said "select ID, max(date1, date2)".

Comment: Instead of giving a date such as '1/1/1973' we can give blank string '' which should get cast to the earliest date as per date type used.. e.g. CAST('' as date) retruns "1900-01-01",  CAST('' as datetime) returns "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" and  CAST('' as datetime2) returns "1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000". This works on SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 12):

From **SQL Server 2012** on, it's possible to use the shortcut [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) to `CASE` expression though the latter is SQL Standard:

```
SELECT ID,
       IIF(DateColA > DateColB, DateColA, DateColB) AS MostRecentDate
  FROM theTable
```

Answer (score 7):

Why couldn't you use the GREATEST function?

```
select id, date1, date2, GREATEST( nvl(date1,date2) , nvl(date2, date1) )
from table1;
```

I included a NVL to ensure that NULL was evaluated correctly, otherwise if either Date1 or Date2 is null, the Greatest returns NULL.

```
ID  Date1       Date2       MostRecentDate
1   1/1/2008    2/1/2008    2/1/2008
2   2/1/2008    1/1/2008    2/1/2008
3   1/10/2008   1/10/2008   1/10/2008
4   -null-      2/10/2008   2/10/2008
5   2/10/2008   -null-      2/10/2008
```

Comment: The question is about SQL-Server not Oracle.

Comment: On SQL 2022, it exists https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15

Comment: No need for the NVL function on SQL Server: "If one or more arguments are not NULL, then NULL arguments will be ignored during comparison. If all arguments are NULL, then GREATEST will return NULL."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest

Answer (score 6):

I think the accepted answer is the simplest.  However, I would watch for null values in the dates...

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(Date1,'01-01-1753') > ISNULL(Date2,'01-01-1753') THEN Date1
            ELSE Date2
       END AS MostRecentDate
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select ID, 
case
when Date1 > Date2 then Date1
else Date2
end as MostRecentDate
from MyTable
```

Comment: looks like we have a consensus :)

Answer (score 5):

You can throw this into a scalar function, which makes handling nulls a little easier. Obviously it isn't going to be any faster than the inline case statement.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [fnGetMaxDateTime] (
    @dtDate1        DATETIME,
    @dtDate2        DATETIME
) RETURNS DATETIME AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dtReturn DATETIME;

    -- If either are NULL, then return NULL as cannot be determined.
    IF (@dtDate1 IS NULL) OR (@dtDate2 IS NULL)
        SET @dtReturn = NULL;

    IF (@dtDate1 > @dtDate2)
        SET @dtReturn = @dtDate1;
    ELSE
        SET @dtReturn = @dtDate2;

    RETURN @dtReturn;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than case statement, I don't believe so...

```
  Select Case When DateColA > DateColB Then DateColA 
              Else DateColB End MostRecent
  From Table ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible, use InLine functions as they suffer none of the performance issues generally associated with UDFs...

```
Create FUNCTION MaximumDate 
(   
@DateTime1 DateTime,
@DateTime2 DateTime
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    Select Case When @DateTime1 > @DateTime2 Then @DateTime1
                Else @DateTime2 End MaxDate
)
GO
```

For usage guidelines, see  [Here](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/101104/sql_server_101104.html)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no built-in function to get the maximum of two values, but you can write your own easily as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMaximumDate(@date1 DATETIME, @date2 DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@date1 > @date2)
        RETURN @date1
    RETURN @date2
END
```

and call it as

```
SELECT Id, dbo.GetMaximumDate(Date1, Date2)
FROM tableName
```

Comment: That's actually what I was going to end up doing for future use. I'm using the case method on this particular problem because of its simplicity, but the maximum date function is something I should have had

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: As mentioned above, depending on which SQL version is being used, as for 2022 GREATEST & LEAST would be to goto functions for this.

Answer (score 1):

All other correct answers as already posted.

But if you are still really looking for MAX keyword then here is a way :

```
select ID , MAX(dt) from 
(  select Id , Date1 as dt from table1
   union  
   select ID , Date2 from table2
) d
group by d.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(d) ChangeDate
from (values(@d), (@d2)) as t(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71022/241211) has several solutions. If you had more than 2 dates to compare, `UNPIVOT` might be preferable to writing a series of `CASE` statements. The following is blatantly stolen from [Niikola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130904/niikola):

```sql
SELECT  id, MAX(dDate) most_recent_date
FROM    your_table
UNPIVOT (d_date FOR n_date IN (date1, date2, date3)) AS u
GROUP BY id
```

Then you can `ORDER BY d_date`, if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,(select max(d) from (select Date1 d uninon select Date2 d) as t) as MaxDate
from MyTable
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.