# How to tell when a sql table was last accessed

Tags: sql-server-2008, statistics

This question is basically an extension of this question:

[How can I tell if a database table is being accessed anymore? Want something like a "SELECT trigger"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155594/how-can-i-tell-if-a-database-table-is-being-accessed-anymore-want-something-lik)

In the query the author provided as a solution in his post, I assume a null value would mean that a table hasn't been accessed since the last time SQL Server was restarted.

My question is:  Is there a way to tell when a table was last accessed, if the last access was before the last time SQL restarted?  Also, how can I tell when the last time SQL was restarted?

Comment: Can you make accessing the data only allowed through a stored procedure?

Comment: @mellamokb There are tons of processes going on, many that I don't even know about yet, that would break if we did that.  From a DBA's perpective SPs are great, but from this developer's perspective they 'usually' don't provide significant benefits to outweigh their downsides.  Jeff Atwood actually has a great article about that on Coding Horror that I completely agree with: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For sql server start time in SQL Server 2008,

```
select sqlserver_start_time from sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

For last user access since server restart,

```
select DB_NAME(us.[database_id]) as [db], OBJECT_NAME(us.[object_id], us.[database_id]) as [object], 
MAX(us.[last_user_lookup]) as [last_user_lookup], MAX(us.[last_user_scan]) as [last_user_scan], MAX(us.[last_user_seek]) as [last_user_seek] 
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats as us 
where us.[database_id] = DB_ID() AND us.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tblname')
group by us.[database_id], us.[object_id];
```

I log this table daily so I have it after restarts. It can also act as an index audit after they have been dropped.