# Can my employer see what tables I look at?

Tags: sql, notifications, tracking

We have several database servers at my work, most of which I have access too. In one server there is a database within that contains a table I want to look at but don't "need" to look at. It's more curiosity, would any one be able to know or be notified if I looked at this table?

Thanks

Comment: Ask the DBA if they log queries.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring to SQL Server. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254485/how-to-tell-when-a-sql-table-was-last-accessed) for a better understanding of how easy it is to track such activities.

Auditing is one of the basic capabilities of any database server. If there is a business need for the DBAs to monitor access to any specific database / table, chances are they might already be logging it. Better ask your DBAs about it if you are really interested in learning about that table.