# How to check if a table is being queried in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to know if there is any way to find out if a table is being queried by some other process in SQL Server.

I am trying to Merge Empty Partitions on a table, and that table is being queried by many process.
So, i need to check if the table is being read/insert by other process,if yes than my merge operation will not proceed. Because if it runs then it gets locked and fails over time.
Due to which sometimes i run out of partitions or i have to run it manually.

Comment: use sql server profiler... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: i need to put a check in the code before merging happens.

Comment: What are your partitions based on? If it is based on dates, you could come up with a better partitioning scheme.

Comment: partitions are based on an interger column.

Comment: Any query that answers the question "Is this table being used?" gives you an answer that is stale before you can act on it.

Comment: Check out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155594/how-can-i-tell-if-a-database-table-is-being-accessed-anymore-want-something-lik

Answer (score 1):

How would possibly help knowing would querying if the table **was** not used? Think about it, any information you get ('no query') is **already obsolete by the time you act**. This is not the way to go, the way to go is simply to reduce the [lock timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx) and attempt to do your operation:

```
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 1;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION ... MERGE ...
```

Comment: this can work for me.. thnx