# GREATEST and LEAST in SQL standard

Tags: sql, standards

My understanding is that GREATEST() and LEAST() are not part of the SQL standard, but are very common.

I'm wondering, **is there a way to clone the functionality of GREATEST keeping within the SQL standard?**

```
SELECT id, GREATEST(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) AS number FROM table
```

The fully query:

```
  SELECT SUBSTR(section,1,2) AS campus, 
           AVG(GREATEST(maximum - enrolled, 0)) AS empty 
    FROM sectionrun 
   WHERE coursenumber = '105' AND subject = 'ENGL' 
GROUP BY campus
```

Comment: For what database?  GREATEST & LEAST are supported by [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/functions-conditional.html), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest), [Oracle](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/greatest.php).  SQL Server is the only one of the majors that doesn't support GREATEST/LEAST.

Comment: I know that PostgreSQL and MySQL support GREATEST/LEAST.  my question involves the actual SQL standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns

Comment: UPDATE: Greatest and least where added to [SQL:2023 as optional feature T054](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/T054). Existing implementation do not always confirm the the new standard in respect to [how NULL values are handled](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/greatest-least#null).

Comment: Too bad Sqlite doesn't support this though you can use max(a,b) and min(a,b) but it's not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression:

```
  SELECT SUBSTR(section,1,2) AS campus, 
           AVG(CASE WHEN maximum - enrolled > 0 
                    THEN maximum - enrolled
                    ELSE 0
               END) AS empty 
    FROM sectionrun 
   WHERE coursenumber = '105' AND subject = 'ENGL' 
GROUP BY campus
```

Comment: This won't scale very well to much more than two values. It's fine for the OPs specific example, but doesn't answer the more general question.

Answer (score 6):

```
GREATEST(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) AS number
```

can become

```
(select max(tmp) from (
        select 1 tmp from dual
        union all
        select 2 tmp from dual
        union all
        select 3 tmp from dual
        union all
        select 4 tmp from dual
        union all
        select 5 tmp from dual
        union all
        select 6 tmp from dual
        union all
        select 7 tmp from dual
) ) AS number
```

Answer (score 3):

As of now, GREATEST() and LEAST() are supported in Azure SQL.  SQL Server 2022 will have it for on-premises installations.

GREATEST documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15