# Getting unique tuples in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table like below i want to get unique values.

```
from_st     to_st       fare
---------------------------
Bangalore   Hyderabad   600
Hyderabad   Bangalore   600
Bangalore   chennai     500
chennai     Bangalore   500
Bangalore   noida       1500
noida       Banagalore  1500
bangalore   delhi       3000
bangalore   pune        2000
```

i need data like Bangalore to Hyderabad and Hyderabad to Bangalore are duplicates. so i want only one records among them.

desired output:

```
from_st     to_st       fare
---------------------------
Bangalore   Hyderabad   600
Bangalore   chennai     500
Bangalore   noida       1500
bangalore   delhi       3000
bangalore   pune        2000
```

Comment: please specify your output more precisely

Comment: I see particularly this question so many times on so many other forums and QA sites. Like  http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/197425/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873643/sql-to-get-distinct-record-for-a-combination-of-two-column-irrespective-of-orde

Comment: @LalitKumarB This is funny. They are the same cities :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this:

```
 select distinct least(from_st, to_st), greatest(from_st, to_st), fare
 from your table;
```