# Compare two columns (date) and update new column with more recent date?

Tags: mysql, date, compare

How can I compare date column foo with the other date column bar and update column foobar with the more recent date.

```
ID        foo                    bar                foobar
1     '2014-01-23'         '0000-00-00'           '0000-00-00'
2     '0000-00-00'         '2013-03-01'           '0000-00-00'
3     '2013-03-03          '2014-04-04'           '0000-00-00'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831901/1563512) use [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET foobar = GREATEST(foo,bar);
```

Comment: i actually ended up using this one, in the end. so i switched my vote. also think its cleaner

Answer (score 2):

this statement updates foobar based on the condition in the [case statement.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/)
Try something like this

```
UPDATE table_name  
SET     foobar =  CASE  
                        WHEN foo < bar THEN foo 
                        ELSE bar
                  END
```