# SQL select most recent date multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, zend-framework

I have a table with an id and 2 datetime fields with over 2000 rows:

Example:

```
id created_at            updated_at
1  2015-07-07 13:39:38   NULL
2  2015-08-06 14:09:14   2015-11-18 10:20:55
3  2015-08-07 11:01:48   2015-11-12 16:43:11
...
```

How can i get a list sorted by the most recent datetime?

`Order by updated_at DESC, created_at DESC` gives me a wrong result. It orders by `updated_at` and then by `created_at` and doesn't give me the expected result.

I also tried several solutions with `CASE WHEN`, but it didn't work for me.

Correct sorted list for the example:

```
id created_at            updated_at
1  2015-08-06 14:09:14   2015-11-18 10:20:55
2  2015-08-07 11:01:48   2015-11-12 16:43:11
3  2015-07-07 13:39:38   NULL
...
```

Comment: Most recent of what? Of created_at, or of updated_at, or the most recent of these two values?

Comment: Most recent of both :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `GREATEST`

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/greatest-function.php

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(created_at, update_at) DESC
```

**EDIT**

You should check how handle null. I think using `0` or maybe use a default date `'1900-1-1'` please test it.

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(
                  COALESCE(created_at, 0),
                  COALESCE(update_at, 0)
                 ) DESC
```

Comment: Of course, GREATEST is the way.

Comment: @jarlh sorry bad spelling :$

Comment: Thanks this worked for me :)

Comment: @jarlh I include an update to handle `NULL` not 100% sure if that is correct, but something similar should work.

Comment: I have no idea if that's needed or not. Doesn't GREATEST handle NULL as expected?

Comment: @jarlh I saw this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831851/mysql-get-max-or-greatest-of-several-columns-but-with-null-fields Looks like doesnt. So just to be safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
select *
from tablename
order by case when created_at is null or created_at < update_at then update_at
              else created_at end desc
```

If created_at is NULL, or created_at is before update_at, then update_at is most recent. Otherwise created_at is most recent. Order by that value desc.

This also works for dbms products without MySQL's `GREATEST` function. If running MySQL, check out Juan Carlos Oropeza's answer instead of this.