# Getting the max or min value of row, but ignoring blank column or 0

Tags: mysql, excel, function, excel-formula

In excel we can find the max. and min. value of a row by ignoring the blank column like this picture

[image]

In mysql database, I have a table with 3 fields, and data types of each field is float. By using the greatest and least function, I intend to find the max. and min. values for each row. But the result is

[image]

The results in excel and in mysql are different, because in excel we can empty the column, but in mysql (with float data type), the empty column will change to 0.

If the column contains NULL, the result is as follows

[image]

**Question :**
Is there a way to make 0 or NULL value in mysql read as empty column?

Comment: I'm not into mysql but someting like `SELECT GREATEST(A,B,C) AS MAX, LEAST(A,B,C) AS MIN FROM value WHERE (A,B,C)!=""` should work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831851/mysql-get-max-or-greatest-of-several-columns-but-with-null-fields May this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use ifnull to substitute a low or a high value

```
drop table if exists t;
Create table t (a float, b float, c float);
insert into t (b,c) values (1,2);
select greatest(ifnull(a,0),ifnull(b,0),ifnull(c,0)) maxi,
         least(ifnull(a,999999),ifnull(b,999999),ifnull(c,999999)) mini
 from t;
```

Result

```
+------+------+
| maxi | mini |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```