# Sql query needs to sort on multiple date columns together

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I have a table with three date fields, a start date, mid-term date, and end date. I would like to create a single query to get the most recent activity from the table. Activity in this case being when the date fields are updated.

Without having to write 3 separate queries and then combining the values in my code to get the 10 most recent activities, can I do this in one query. So right now I have

```
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM core_table 
    ORDER BY [start_date] Desc

    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM core_table 
    ORDER BY [process_date] Desc

    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM core_table 
    ORDER BY [archive_date] Desc
```

So I would want to pull the results of those three queries together to get the top 10 entries based on all three dates.

Comment: looking for something like this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns

Comment: That I think gets the top row for each row, not a collection of rows, but helpful anyways. thanks!

Comment: I think Sven's solution from that post should work for you since it effectively calculates the max date for each row. You can then sort and filter on this calculated column: SELECT [other fields,]
(SELECT Max(v) FROM (VALUES (date1),(date2),(date3),...) AS value(v)) as [MaxDate],
FROM [YourTable]

Comment: @Mike - Thanks, I got the answer I need. If people think this is a duplicate I'm fine with it being closed, got what I need!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

based on answer given by Itiong_sh, which is not exactly the same : you can do it in ORDER BY

```
select top 10 * from core_table
order by
  CASE
      WHEN start_date >= process_date AND start_date >= archive_date 
          THEN  start_date
      WHEN process_date >= archive_date 
          THEN  process_date
      ELSE  archive_date
  END
 DESC
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! I added DESC after the END to get the dates in the order I wanted, but that takes care of the multiple date fields!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `UNION`:

```
SELECT TOP 10               
    *
FROM
    (   ( SELECT TOP 10 
              *, start_date    AS activity_date
          FROM core_table 
          ORDER BY [start_date] DESC
        ) 
    UNION
        ( SELECT TOP 10 
              *, process_date  AS activity_date
          FROM core_table 
          ORDER BY [process_date] DESC
        ) 
    UNION
        ( SELECT TOP 10 
              *, archive_date  AS activity_date
          FROM core_table 
          ORDER BY [archive_date] DESC
        )
    ) AS t
ORDER BY activity_date DESC ;
```

Comment: That was one of my first thoughts but I'm getting incorrect syntax, ORDER BY clauses have to be outside of the UNION. Not sure if that is a T-Sql thing or just SQL in general.

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm sticking with Raphael's solutions b/c it has the side benefit of being in order by the combined dates. Your solution gives the top 10+ rows but orders them by the Primary Key column.

Comment: See my edit. You can choose how many of the (30) rows you want changing the TOP 10 in the first line of the code.

Comment: @ypercube I don't think this is correct. The `UNION` will compare all fields, including `activity_date`, which can have different values for the _same_ table row (since it will take its value from different fields). You'll end-up with unwanted duplicates.

Comment: @Branko: You are right off course. Then a modification of the external query is needed (unless the OP wants exactly this, a row to appear more than once if it has been both processed and updated recently)

Answer (score 2):

An expansion on [Raphaël Althaus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10568231/533120):

```
CREATE TABLE core_table (
    ...
    max_date AS
        CASE
            WHEN start_date >= process_date AND start_date >= archive_date
                THEN start_date
            WHEN process_date >= archive_date
                THEN process_date
            ELSE archive_date
        END
);

CREATE INDEX core_table_ie1 ON core_table (max_date);
```

Then, you can simply...

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM core_table
ORDER BY max_date DESC;
```

...and it should use the index range scan instead of a full table scan.