# Greatest value of multiple columns with column name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have explored many questions and answers regarding how to return the greatest values from multiple columns along with column name. But I have not solved the problem
here in this question will explain:

[SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)

But I don't know how to figure out the column name having greatest value? Any ideas?

Comment: Use the exact same thing. `case ... then 'column_name'`.

Comment: yea, got it, thanks. plz post the answer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: I think no, because of trying best to find column name at same alies  but not exceded!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function to find the maximum value among all columns:

```
SELECT @var_max_val:= GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, ...) AS max_value,
       CASE @var_max_val WHEN col1 THEN 'col1'
                         WHEN col2 THEN 'col2'
                         ...
       END AS max_value_column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE ...
```

Comment: yea! same is but for column name case statement is needed in qry as well