# Need to get first date in multiple column table

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with multiple date column, and i need to get the first date within all the column. I have a SQL query to get all the first date in column, but how can i get the first date within the result? The final result i need is just 1 first/earliest date within all column.

My Query:

```
SELECT
(SELECT EventDate1 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate1 !='' ORDER BY EventDate1 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_1,
(SELECT EventDate2 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate2 !='' ORDER BY EventDate2 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_2,
(SELECT EventDate3 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate3 !='' ORDER BY EventDate3 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_3,
(SELECT EventDate4 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate4 !='' ORDER BY EventDate4 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_4,
(SELECT EventDate5 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate5 !='' ORDER BY EventDate5 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_5,
(SELECT EventDate6 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate6 !='' ORDER BY EventDate6 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_6,
(SELECT EventDate7 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate7 !='' ORDER BY EventDate7 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_7,
(SELECT EventDate8 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate8 !='' ORDER BY EventDate8 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_8,
(SELECT EventDate9 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate9 !='' ORDER BY EventDate9 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_9,
(SELECT EventDate10 FROM 33160_30006_feed WHERE EventDate10 !='' ORDER BY EventDate10 LIMIT 1) AS EventDate_10
```

My Result:

```
EventDate_1|EventDate_2|EventDate_3|EventDate_4|EventDate_5|EventDate_6|EventDate_7|EventDate_8|EventDate_9|EventDate_10|
 2015-06-01| 2015-03-25| 2015-03-27| 2015-03-26| 2015-03-24| 2015-05-08| 2015-03-25| 2015-03-25| 2015-03-29|  2015-03-25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would select the minimum over the union of the dates:

```
SELECT MIN(AllEventDates.EventDate)
FROM
(
    SELECT EventDate1 AS EventDate FROM 33160_30006_feed
    UNION
    SELECT EventDate2 AS EventDate FROM 33160_30006_feed
    UNION
    SELECT EventDateN AS EventDate FROM 33160_30006_feed
) AS AllEventDates
WHERE AllEventDates.EventDate != ''
```

Comment: Patrick, i try with your query, but i get following error, what should i do?
MySQL said: Documentation

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Adding an ` AS AllEventDates` after the last closing bracket will fix this.

Comment: Move the AS AllEventDates out of the ) bracket and it work. Thanks rostbot and guys.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) or [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

See [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195655/685760) on this issue and see if that helps too.