# How Do I Select Multiple tables and columns values by Highest Number

Tags: php

I Have A `Table` Called skill in Which i Have Different `Fields` Like

```
skillPer1 SkillPer2 SkillPer3 ..... skillPer8. (skillPer=skillPercentage)
```

and another table called user which contains userImage and etc.. so i want to combine this two tables for skill result as well as user profile in same div

So When User Stores His `Skill` in `%` Out Of 100 Then I want To display The `highest` K From Those 8 skillPer fields

For Example User Has Store `skillPer1` in `PHP` `80%` `skillPer2` in `C++` `90%` so That i want to display `highest` `%` from those table fields that is `90%` 
So Basically I want This Two Statements two be combine together and get the user Profile as well as his skill Highest % but i cant figured it out how to do that

```
 <?php 
 $userID=$_REQUEST['userID'];
  $sql1= "(SELECT *, @maxVal:= GREATEST(skillPer1,skillPer2,skillPer3,skillPer4,skillPer5,skillPer6,skillPer7,skillPer8) as higherPercentage,
CASE @maxVal 
WHEN skillPer1 THEN 'skillPer1'
WHEN skillPer2 THEN 'skillPer2'
WHEN skillPer3 THEN 'skillPer3'
WHEN skillPer4 THEN 'skillPer4'
WHEN skillPer5 THEN 'skillPer5'
WHEN skillPer6 THEN 'skillPer6'
WHEN skillPer7 THEN 'skillPer7'
WHEN skillPer8 THEN 'skillPer8'
       END AS max_value_skill_name
FROM `skill`) ";         
 $res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {

?>

<?php 
$userID = intval($_SESSION['userid']);
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY signup_date DESC)"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
?>

 <?php echo '../uploads/'.$row['userImage'];?>
<?php echo '../uploads/'.$row1['skillPercentage'];?>

<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL, look up the `GREATEST()` function

Comment: plz can you give me a small example of what i have discussed for select statement

Answer (score 0):

You can write sql query like below....

```
SELECT id, GREATEST(a,b,c,d) as higherPercentage FROM `your_table`;
```

in above example a,b,c and d are the columns...
hope this will help...

to get max value percentage with its skill column try below...

```
SELECT *, @maxVal:= GREATEST(a,b,c,d) as higherPercentage,
CASE @maxVal WHEN a THEN 'a'
WHEN b THEN 'b'
WHEN c THEN 'c'
WHEN d THEN 'd'
       END AS max_value_skill_name
FROM `your_table`
```

it will return result like..
[image: resultset]

Comment: you will get max value of percentage in "higherPercentage " this column

Comment: is it essential to create higherPercentage column or i shud echo it directly

Comment: you can directly echo it, but I think your problem will be remain for which skill you are getting this max value? for that you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195558/greatest-value-of-multiple-columns-with-column-name

Comment: Any One here for my help

Comment: Hi, as i can see your modified questions and code. so you can use join to combine both the tables, you can add join on users table with skills table, of course you need common user_id field in both the tables. so basically you don't need to fire separate queries, you can do this like `SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;` also please add where clause in your query to filter record for single user. as i can see you have user id in your session.

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` `GREATEST()` function returns the greatest of the given arguments.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection ,"SELECT id, GREATEST(Skill1,Skill2,Skill3,........) as highestskillPercentage FROM table") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$id = $row['id'];
$percentahe = $row['highestskillPercentage'];
```

if you will not use AS `highestskillPercentage` you will get output like

```
GREATEST(Skill1,Skill2,skill3,skill4…………………...)
90
48
78
23
85
```

but if you use `highestskillPercentage` you will get

```
 highestskillPercentage
    90
    48
    78
    23
    85
```

Comment: im confuse with the highestskillPercentage field is it mandatory to create in the table and what is this use for ?

Comment: no its not but if you will not use this this then in running query directly in phpmyadmin you will get its header as GREATEST(skill1,skill2...) but in runnning code using php it is blank so we have to use a name

Comment: so basically i have to echo higherskillPercentage for my highest result

Comment: any One Here For My Answer ?