# RE: Greatest Value with column name

Tags: postgresql

[Greatest value of multiple columns with column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195558/greatest-value-of-multiple-columns-with-column-name)

I was reading the question above (link above) and the "ACCEPTED" answer (which seems correct) and have several questions concerning this answer.

(Sorry I have to create a new post, don't have a high enough reputation to comment on the old post as it seems very old)

**Questions**
My first question is what is the significance of "@var_max_val:= "? I reran the query without it and everything ran fine.

My second question is can someone explain how this achieve it's desired result:

```
 CASE @var_max_val WHEN col1 THEN 'col1'
                     WHEN col2 THEN 'col2'
                     ...
   END AS max_value_column_name
```

My third question is as follows:

It seems that in this "case" statement he manually has to write a line of code ("when x then y") for every column in the table. This is fine if you have 1-5 columns. But what if you had 10,000? How would you go about it?

---

PS: I might be violating some forum rules in this post, do let me know if I am. 
Thank you for reading, and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5):

The linked question is about mysql so it does not apply to postgresql (e.g. the `@var_max_val` syntax is specific to mysql). To accomplish the same thing in postgresql you can use a `LATERAL` subquery. For example, suppose that you have the following table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,2,3), (5,8,6);
```

Then you can identify the maximum column for each row with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t, LATERAL (
            VALUES ('col1',col1),('col2',col2),('col3',col3)
            ORDER BY 2 DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) l(maxcolname, maxcolval);
```

which produces the following output:

```
 col1 | col2 | col3 | maxcolname | maxcolval 
------+------+------+------------+-----------
    1 |    2 |    3 | col3       |         3
    5 |    8 |    6 | col2       |         8
```

I think this solution is much more elegant than the one presented in the linked article for mysql.

As for having to manually write the code, unfortunately, I do not think you can avoid that.

Comment: just a quick note, this `
SELECT GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, ...) AS max_value,
       CASE  WHEN col1 THEN 'col1'
                         WHEN col2 THEN 'col2'
                         ...
       END AS max_value_column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE ...`

works in postgres

Comment: The `GREATEST` function does exists in postgresql, but the linked article also uses user defined variables that are specific to mysql.

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres 9.5 you can use [jsonb functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) to get column names. In this case you do not have to write manually all the columns names. The solution needs a primary key (or a unique column) for proper 
grouping:

```
create table a_table(id serial primary key, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);
insert into a_table (col1, col2, col3) values (1,2,3), (5,8,6);

select distinct on(id) id, key, value
from a_table t, jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t))
where key <> 'id'
order by id, value desc;

 id | key  | value 
----+------+-------
  1 | col3 | 3
  2 | col2 | 8
(2 rows)
```

Comment: getting error `ERROR: function to_jsonb(a_table) does not exist
SQL state: 42883`

Comment: @Paarth `to_jsonb` was added in 9.5, are you using that version?