# How to use MAX function in a SQL Server update statement

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know whether the following can be done..

```
DECLARE @IsDefault bit

SELECT @IsDefault = IsDefault FROM <TABLE> WHERE <CONDITIONS>

UPDATE <TABLE> 
SET IsDefault = max(IsDefault,@IsDefault) WHERE <CONDITIONS>
```

Comment: Look fro `COALESCE` or `ISNULL`.

Comment: You do know that `variables` can only store 1 value. `@IsDefault` will only have last value assigned. It is not clear what is it that you actually want to do here.

Comment: Yes...however,is it possible to get the max between the value stored in variable @IsDefault and the value stored in the column IsDefault for the conditions given.

Comment: The answer is probably yes, but your question is too vague. are you trying to set the value of all IsDefault in the table to the max value of IsDefault?

Comment: The idea is to compare the values of @IsDefault (variable) and the value already in the column IsDefault for certain conditions in the WHERE clause,and update with the max of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX()-function is an aggregate function, and as such you can not use it to compare two values and return only the largest. You have to do something like this instead:

```
UPDATE <TABLE>
SET IsDefault = CASE WHEN IsDefault > @IsDefault THEN IsDefault ELSE @IsDefault END
WHERE <CONDITIONS>
```

Similarly for the MIN()-function.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, if you were pulling this value out into a variable to make things more clear, and could in fact use two sets, this is an interesting way to solve this problem that I've needed before.

`SELECT [Other Fields],
  (SELECT Max(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (date1), (date2), (date3),...) AS value(v)) as [MaxDate]
FROM [YourTableName]`

It should be noted that this only works on sql server >= 2008.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871572/1316081