# find max value in a row and update new column with the max column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have a table like this

```
number  col1   col2   col3   col4  max
---------------------------------------
  0     200    150    300     80         
 16      68    250    null    55
```

I want to find max value between col1,col2,col3,col4 in every row and update the last column "max"  with the max value column name!

for example in first row max value is 300 the "max" column value will be "col3"
result like this:

```
number   col1   col2   col3    col4   max
------------------------------------------
  0      200    150    300      80    col3
 16       68    250    null     55    col2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: no its fixed and its 5 col i wrote here only 4.

Answer (score 3):

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT *,(
SELECT MAX(n) 
    FROM
    (
        VALUES(col1),(col2),(col3),(col4)
    ) AS t(n)
)  AS maximum_value
FROM #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update statement**

```
with MaxValues
    as (select [number], [max] = (
          select (
            select max ([n])
              from (values ([col1]) , ([col2]) , ([col3]) , ([col4])) as [t] ([n])
          ) as [maximum_value])
          from [#tmpTable]) 
    update [#tmpTable]
      set [max] = [mv].[max]
      from [MaxValues] [mv]
           join [#tmpTable] on [mv].[number] = [#tmpTable].[number];
```

assuming *number* is a key column

Answer (score 0):

### SQL Fiddle

Check in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98a31e/1)

### Schema

```
DECLARE @temp table ([number] int NOT NULL, [col1] int, [col2] int, [col3] int, [col4] int, [colmax] int);

INSERT @temp VALUES (0, 200, 150, 300, 80, null), (16, 68, 250, null, 55, null);
```

### Query

```
SELECT number
    ,(
        SELECT MAX(col) maxCol
        FROM (
            SELECT t.col1 AS col

            UNION

            SELECT t.col2

            UNION

            SELECT t.col3

            UNION

            SELECT t.col4
            ) a
        ) col
FROM @temp t
```

and the update statement is -

```
UPDATE tempCol
SET colmax = a.col
FROM (
SELECT (
        SELECT MAX(col) maxCol
        FROM (
            SELECT t.col1 AS col

            UNION

            SELECT t.col2

            UNION

            SELECT t.col3

            UNION

            SELECT t.col4
            ) a
        ) col
FROM tempCol t
) a
```