# how to calculate top 3 results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with multiple columns such as

```
RacerID | Round1 | Round2 | Round3 | Round4 | Total
  2         100      100      96       99      395                                            
  5         99       97       100      96      392
```

how can i query out the top 3 results from columns (round1, round2, round3, round4) so that it should display

```
racerid | Top3Rounds
   2         299                
   5         296
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: you want sql query or php code ? and did you try anything ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: You could also consider normalising your data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

may be this:

```
SELECT RacerID ,  round1 + round2 + round3 + round4 - LEAST(round1, round2, round3, round4) AS Top3Rounds
FROM tablename
```

Fiddle example [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/546f5/7).

Comment: Took the liberty to add the fiddle.

Comment: that's brilliant, works like a charm thanks OTARIKI and Raging Bull, all i have to do now is tweak it to make it pull in the rounds dynamically and boom job done :)

Comment: sorry to be a pain guys, that code works great, but what if there were 12 rounds, and we need best of 7? 
many thanks