# Best Practice for returning the highest value in a set of columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Isn't my Forte, Some help from you experts would be amazing :)

Dataset:

```
 Name of Product  |  Part Number   |   Size 1  |  Size 2 |  Size 3
------------------|----------------|-----------|---------|----------
      Item1       |    12345       |     4     |    4    |     6
      Item2       |    54321       |     4     |    5    |     4
      Item3       |    54123       |     6     |    2    |     2
```

I need to return the highest value in the 3 sizes and aggregate them into a single column.

```
Item1  |  6
Item2  |  5
Item3  |  6
```

Googling has only lead me to the MAX() function, but it just returns the highest value in the dataset which is not what im after.

Comment: Use `group by` with `max()`.

Comment: Yup, I didnt find that post, sorry for the duplicate. @AHiggens your answer worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Spoke too soon, getting a '% has more columns than were specified in the column list.' on the value part of value(val)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `UNPIVOT` to split out the columns, and then the Maximum becomes a simple `MAX()` with `GROUP BY` against the relevant `[Name of Product]`

```
SELECT [Name of Product], Max(TheSize)
FROM Table1
UNPIVOT
(
    [TheSize]
    FOR Size in ([Size 1], [Size 2], [Size 3])
) x
GROUP BY [Name of Product];
```

[SqlFiddle is back online - example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a23cd/1)

Comment: This got it working, just had to add the rest of the fields in the table to the group by, thanks!

Comment: Aha - hopefully you've solved the problem? Unfortunately SqlFiddle isn't working with SqlServer at the moment, but I do have a working sample.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of SQL Server (2008 or above), you could use a variation on the following:

```
SELECT 
    [Name Of Product],
    (SELECT MAX(Val)    FROM (VALUES ([Size 1]), ([Size 2]), ([Size 3])) AS value(val)) AS MaxSize
FROM MyTable
```

EDIT: Found the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871572/1225845) source of this code, will mark your question as a potential duplicate based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested CASE statement. Someting like this:

```
SELECT [name of product], [part number], CASE WHEN size1 > size2 AND size1 > size 3 Then size1 ELSE CASE WHEN size2 > size 3 THEN size 2 ELSE size 3 END END
FROM ...
```