# Select the fields from different tables

Tags: mysql, outsystems

I need to select different fields from different databases. One of the field  is selecting the maximum of the LastUpdateOn datetime field from different tables.

{Project},{Document},{Instruction},{Document}, {User}, {ProjectParticipant} are the different tables

```
SELECT {Project}.[Number],{Project}.[Name],{User}.[Last_Login],{A}.[max_LastUpdatedOn]

From {Project}

INNER JOIN {ProjectParticipant} ON {Project}.[Id] = {ProjectParticipant}.[ProjectId]
INNER JOIN {User} ON {ProjectParticipant}.[UserId] = {User}.[Id] AND {User}.[Username] = @UserId
INNER JOIN {Document} ON {Project}.[Id] = {Document}.[ProjectId]
INNER JOIN {InstructionType} ON {Project}.[Id] = {Instruction}.[ProjectId]
INNER JOIN {Question}  ON {Project}.[Id] = {Question}.[ProjectId]

SELECT MAX(LastUpdatedOn) AS max_LastUpdatedOn
FROM 
(
  SELECT LastUpdatedOn FROM {Question}
  UNION ALL
  SELECT LastUpdatedOn FROM {Document}
  UNION ALL
  SELECT LastUpdatedOn FROM {Instruction}
) A;

GROUP BY {Project}.[Number],
         {Project}.[Name],
         {User}.[Last_Login]
         {A}.[max_LastUpdatedOn]
ORDER BY {Project}.[Number]
```

But getting an error saying {A} is an unknown entity. I am not sure what is wrong here. 
Tried using the

```
SELECT {Project}.[Number],{Project}.[Name],{User}.[Last_Login],
(SELECT MAX(LastUpdatedOn) as max_LastUpdatedOn
 FROM
 (
  SELECT {Question}.[LastUpdatedOn] where {Project}.[Id] = {Question}.[ProjectId]
  UNION ALL
  Select {Document}.[LastUpdatedOn] where {Project}.[Id] = {Document}.[ProjectId]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT {Instruction}.[LastUpdatedOn] where {Project}.[Id] = {Instruction}.[ProjectId]
  )
  A ) [max_LastUpdatedOn]

 FROM {Project}
 INNER JOIN {ProjectParticipant} ON {Project}.[Id] = {ProjectParticipant}.[ProjectId]
 INNER JOIN {User} ON ({ProjectParticipant}.[UserId] = {User}.[Id] AND {User}.[Username] = @UserId)
 INNER JOIN {Question}  ON {Project}.[Id] = {Question}.[ProjectId]
 INNER JOIN {Document} ON {Project}.[Id] = {Document}.[ProjectId]
 INNER JOIN {Instruction} ON {Project}.[Id] = {Instruction}.[ProjectId]

 GROUP BY {Project}.[Number],
          {Project}.[Name],
          {User}.[Last_Login],
          A.[max_LastUpdatedOn]
 ORDER BY {Project}.[Number]
```

Getting an error  like The multi-part identifier "A.max_LastUpdatedOn" could not be bound.

Comment: for the love of Pete get rid of the squigglies. What is A. If A is a database how would it even work

Comment: A stores the maximum of the LastUpdatedOn fields from Question Document and Instruction tables

Comment: There's quite a few problems; you're using invalid syntax (the `{}` and `[]` which are not valid in MySQL), and just plugging the query that gets the last_updated into another query won't work. It would be best if you specified your tables and how they are connected and what you want to do.

Comment: I am using the Sql Advanced query in Outsystems, I need to use {} for table and [] for field.

Comment: But you said different database where is that

Comment: I am sorry different tables

Comment: No prob edit question and Title

Comment: So see if you have a table A

Comment: A is having the selected  maximum of the LastUpdatedOn fields from Question Document and Instruction tables

Comment: Maybe you are in the wrong database. Maybe the command is `use !dbname¡` ;)

Comment: How do I select the here the maximum of LastUpdatedOn which are on the different tables here.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://pastebin.com/FUQUdYH7 It might be what you want if what you want is to get the lastupdated value per projectid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{A}` is not an OutSystems Entity, therefore you should not use curly braces to refer it. Curly braces are used to translate from the *meta model* name in design time to the *physical table name* in the database.

Since `A` is a simple alias of the inner select statement, just using `A` should be enough to make it work. For example:

```
SELECT {Project}.[Number],{Project}.[Name],{User}.[Last_Login],A.[max_LastUpdatedOn]
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding the error about `The multi-part identifier could not be bound`, it has to do with grouping by something that is not in the `from`/`join` sources of the query.

I haven’t tried this code below, but something like this should do the trick:
*(also, see here more ways on how to select the [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns))*

```
SELECT {Project}.[Number], {Project}.[Name], {User}.[Last_Login], 
    CASE
        WHEN {Question}.[LastUpdatedOn] >= {Document}.[LastUpdatedOn] AND {Question}.[LastUpdatedOn] >= {Instruction}.[LastUpdatedOn]
        THEN {Question}.[LastUpdatedOn]
        WHEN {Document}.[LastUpdatedOn] >= {Instruction}.[LastUpdatedOn] THEN {Document}.[LastUpdatedOn]
        ELSE {Instruction}.[LastUpdatedOn]
    END AS max_LastUpdatedOn
FROM {Project}
INNER JOIN {ProjectParticipant} ON {Project}.[Id] = {ProjectParticipant}.[ProjectId]
INNER JOIN {User} ON ({ProjectParticipant}.[UserId] = {User}.[Id] AND {User}.[Username] = @UserId)
INNER JOIN {Question}  ON {Project}.[Id] = {Question}.[ProjectId]
INNER JOIN {Document} ON {Project}.[Id] = {Document}.[ProjectId]
INNER JOIN {Instruction} ON {Project}.[Id] = {Instruction}.[ProjectId]
GROUP BY {Project}.[Number], 
         {Project}.[Name], 
         {User}.[Last_Login]
ORDER BY {Project}.[Number]
```

Comment: I tried using just A as shown in the question but even that is giving me an error like The multi-part identifier "A.max_LastUpdatedOn" could not be bound.

Comment: Ah, but that’s another issue… the error saying “{A} is an unknown entity” is fixed by removing the curly braces. “The multi-part identifier could not be bound” is caused by trying to `GROUP BY` on something that isn’t present in any of the `FROM`/`JOIN` clauses.