# How do I determine the highest value of three columns from the same row, Python, SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite, average

I am trying to display the results of a basic arithmetic test created in python, the test is repeated three times and collects three scores, this works fine, however whe I try to display these by the highest score of the three in descending order I am displayed an error message. which is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Adair,Rowan CA2\Task 3\Code\DisplayTablesScore.py", line 4, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM class1 ORDER BY (score1,score2,score3) DESC")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

However when it is organised by one of the columns e.g. only score 1 it works fine. 
The code that I cannot figure out how to fix is below.

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("class1.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM class1 ORDER BY (score1,score2,score3) DESC")
print("Class 1:")
result = cursor.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Any help with this would be immensly appreciated, I am also trying to determine the average aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the syntax of ORDER BY its wrong, should be

```
SELECT * FROM class1 ORDER BY score1 DESC, score2 DESC, score3 DESC;
```

Based in the response of [Max of multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns), if you need to order by the high score of the columns, you need to calculate them

```
SELECT score1, score2, score3,
    CASE
    WHEN score1 >= score2 AND score1 >= score3 THEN score1
    WHEN score2 >= score1 AND score2 >= score3 THEN score2
    WHEN score3 >= score1 AND score3 >= score2 THEN score3
    ELSE score1
END AS high_score FROM class1 ORDER BY high_score DESC;
```

Comment: Apologies but could you display that implemented intot the program, having trouble with implementation.

Comment: Ok, you only need to put the query in the `cursor.execute(''' SELECT ...''')` and will work

Answer (score 0):

The SQL clause `ORDER BY` doesn't take parentheses when declaring its arguments. In other words, doing `ORDER BY (...)` is indeed invalid syntax.

To declare multiple columns to order against, just omit the parentheses:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM class1 ORDER BY score1 DESC, score2 DESC ,score3 DESC")
```

[This example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) should cover the basics. Note that each column may require its own descension/ascension keyword.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to impliment this into the program.

Comment: Just replace the `cursor.execute ()` you already have now. If that isn't working, could you be more specific about what the error is?