# SQL Server Count data in 2 columns with different values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to make a smart count operation, so that if the data in columns are the same, then it will be counted as 1.

My table is:

```
dbo.Messages 
(
    FromUserId INT,
    ToUserId INT
)
```

Data:

```
INSERT dbo.Messages VALUES(1, 5), (2, 20), (5, 1), (1, 5);
```

The count should return 2 because (1,5) and (5,1) is the same in my algorithm.

How can I write it in SQL Server TSQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works quite well:

```
CREATE TABLE #Messages 
(
    FromUserId INT,
    ToUserId INT
);

INSERT #Messages VALUES(1, 5), (2, 20), (5, 1), (1, 5);

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT M1.FromUserId, M1.ToUserId
  FROM #Messages AS M1
  EXCEPT
  SELECT M2.ToUserId, M2.FromUserId
  FROM #Messages AS M2
  WHERE M2.ToUserId > M2.FromUserId
  ) AS T;
```

Derived table with `EXCEPT` will remove your duplicates and then it just counts so called unique values. Keep in mind that here's no need for `DISTINCT` keyword, `EXCEPT` removes all dupes.

Results from derived table:

```
FromUserId ToUserId 
---------- -------- 
1          5        
2          20
```

You can check how this query works here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/524634/counting-unique-values

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about this is to group by the least and greatest of the `FromUserId` and `ToUserId`, using the distinct values from your original table.  Since SQL Server, unlike MySQL, does not have a `LEAST` and `GREATEST` function, we can use `CASE` expressions instead.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.FromUserId < t.ToUserId THEN t.FromUserId ELSE t.ToUserId END,
       CASE WHEN t.FromUserId < t.ToUserId THEN t.ToUserId   ELSE t.FromUserId END,
       COUNT(*) AS duplicateCount
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT FromUserId, ToUserId
    FROM dbo.Messages
) t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN t.FromUserId < t.ToUserId THEN t.FromUserId ELSE t.ToUserId END,
         CASE WHEN t.FromUserId < t.ToUserId THEN t.ToUserId   ELSE t.FromUserId END
```

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2008 and later this should work:

```
SELECT distinct
    (SELECT Min(v) FROM (VALUES (FromUserId), (ToUserId)) AS value(v)) as UserIdMin,
    (SELECT Max(v) FROM (VALUES (FromUserId), (ToUserId)) AS value(v)) as UserIdMax
FROM dbo.Messages
```

Cred to: [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns/6871572#6871572)

Comment: This is great answer. To add something up, you don't need two seperate subqueries and could use `CROSS APPLY` to return both `MIN` and `MAX` values. Here's an example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/524750/counting-unique-values

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[Demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/524739)</kbd>

```
select distinct  t1.*
from
#temp t1
join
#temp t2
on t1.FromUserId=t2.ToUserId
and t1.ToUserId=t2.FromUserId
```

Comment: I don't think it meets A/C. If you would remove count and keep just distinct, it brings back 1 and 5 and that seems wrong. 1, 5 and 5, 1 should be treated as same.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas:User is asking for count  and in this case it returns2,did you saw the demo

Comment: I did. But it just happens that it brings 2. Edit data and your query doesn't work anymore. It will bring back incorrect count.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas:thanks ,i was thinking of this line from users question whole time "count should return 2" ,updated now