# Using a SQL WHERE clause on Max value of Multiple Columns

Tags: sql

I found a great solution to return the max value of multiple columns ([SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns/6871572#6871572?newreg=d1235207d8614fa2b3eb9551f1df1cf9)).  See below.  It works great for my application, but I have no idea how to run a WHERE on the [MaxDate] value.  I can't seem to figure our the column name.

```
SELECT [Other Fields],
    (SELECT Max(v) 
     FROM (VALUES (date1), (date2), (date3),...) AS value(v)) as [MaxDate]
FROM [YourTableName]
WHERE [MaxDate] = '2016-01-01'  <---I know this is wrong but need help
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` for getting the maximum date instead of using a subquery in the `SELECT`, in this way you have the `MaxDate` column available for the `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT [Other Fields], MaxDate
FROM YourTableName
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Max(v) 
  FROM (VALUES (date1), (date2), (date3), [...]) AS value(v))
  AS Dates (MaxDate)
WHERE MaxDate='2016-01-01'
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto...this is exactly what I was looking for, and it works.  Now I can use the WHERE condition!!!!

Comment: Won't a CROSS APPLY here run for each row in the SELECT? I'd check out the query plan on this and make sure it will scale. This may get slow for a large dataset from <YourTableName>.

Comment: @Shawn I'm not sure about how `CROSS APPLY` would be processed in this situation, but the alternative is run the query directly in the `SELECT` list and that case it should be processed for each row almost sure (so in the worst case if offers the same performance).

Answer (score 2):

The fields in the SELECT don't exist before a WHERE. Take a peak at https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/.

SQL's normal processing order is:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
   10 ORDER BY
10. TOP

So in your query, there is no [maxDate] available yet. To have one available for a WHERE, use a CTE to generate one. Then apply the WHERE.

*NOTE: I used INTs for the `VALUE()` columns for simplicity's sake.*

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5058/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t (field1 varchar(10), f2 int, f3 int, f4 int ) ;

INSERT INTO t (field1, f2, f3, f4) 
VALUES ('first',10,5,0), ('second',1,7,3), ('third',2,4,6) ;
```

**Query 1**:

```
; WITH a AS (
  SELECT field1,
    (
      SELECT Max(v) 
      FROM (VALUES (f2), (f3), (f4)) AS value(v)
    ) AS maxF
  FROM t
)
SELECT a.field1, a.maxF
FROM a 
WHERE a.maxF = 6 ;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5058/1/0)**:

```
| field1 | maxF |
|--------|------|
|  third |    6 |
```

Comment: Shawn, thanks for your reply, but I guess I'm really not that well in SQL to see how I can apply this to my current query.  My current query is much more complex compared to the example I provided.  I have updated my SQL code to illustrate where my problem is.  Thanks.

Comment: His suggestion is that you embed (as a CTE) your existing query, minus the `WHERE` clause, into another query that passes all of the data through, but applies a `WHERE`. His` maxF=6` is your `MaxDate='2016-01-01'`.