# Can you MAX(*) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am dealing with a huge list of columns (around 50) where i only need to group by one column. Is there anyway in SQL Server i can aggregate the columns by something such as

```
SELECT MAX(*)
FROM View1
GROUP BY Column1
```

instead of having to go through each one and specify an aggregate function. I have had a look online but cant find anything. Is there any advice or guidance someone can give me or is it just a case of going through each row?

Thanks

Comment: No. Seems like an odd table design.

Comment: That is not valid syntax in any SQL product I know, including SQL Server.

Comment: So what would the expected output of that be? The maximum value of the biggest column? The maximum value of the sum of all columns? What if there are non-numeric columns in the table? Maybe you should take a step back and explain the underlying problem by showing some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. ([Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)).

Comment: See [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: Simple select top 1000 rows by right clicking table . u will have all column names displayed in query window, select the aggregate column u wanted . a simple shortcut

Comment: It is a common situation to me. F.e. you are building facts table, and it consist of 50 columns. And you need to use aggregation on half of this columns. Ctrl+c ctrl+v 25 times, then put ') as columnname'.. it takes time :)

Comment: @gofr1 there are better ways to do this kind of stuff. Notepad++ supports vertical block editing, plus a good regexp replace will go a long way for your use-case

Comment: @trailmax You are totally right :) I have shared SQL-way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build query you need using system tables:

```
DECLARE @ViewName sysname = N'View1',
        @query nvarchar(max),
        @Column sysname = 'Column1'

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @Column + ',' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @query = @query + N'MAX('+c.[name]+') as '+c.[name]+',' + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.views v
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON v.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
WHERE v.[name] = @ViewName AND c.[name] != @Column


SET @query = STUFF(@query,LEN(@query)-1,1,'') + 'FROM '+@ViewName + CHAR(10) + 'GROUP BY ' + @Column

PRINT @query
```

Output will be:

```
SELECT Column1,
MAX(Column2) as Column2,
MAX(Column3) as Column3,
...
MAX(ColumnN) as ColumnN
FROM View1
GROUP BY Column1
```

You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on new query window and execute, or execute it right here with:

```
EXEC (@query)
```

In case of tables - you need to use `sys.tables`

In case if view or table is not in default schema - you need to specify it manually.

```
SET @query = STUFF(@query,LEN(@query)-1,1,'') + 'FROM dbo.'+@ViewName + CHAR(10) + 'GROUP BY ' + @Column
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, you're going to have to write out the columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you need max value from different columns you can try as below

```
Select max(yourcolumn) from
(
    Select col1 from yourtable
    union all Select col2 from yourtable
    union all Select col3 from yourtable
    ...
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use max(*).
You will have to give a column name in max function like below

```
select max(column_name) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write `select max(*)`.  This results in the error `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`  Instead, you will need to specify the columns.

One way to get the maximum of multiple columns is to `unpivot` the table.  An efficient way to do this is to use `cross apply` to generate separate row values for each column.

For example, the code below finds the maximum value across 3 different columns in all of the rows:

```
declare @test table
(
    id int primary key clustered,
    value1 int,
    value2 int,
    value3 int
)

insert into @test (id, value1, value2, value3)
values (1, 100, 0, 0), (2, 0, 50, 0), (3, 0, 0, 25)

select max(TestValue) -- returns 100
from @test
cross apply
(
    values(value1),(value2), (value3)
) TestValues (TestValue)
```