# Combine multiple lists and find maximum

Tags: python, pandas

Can pandas combine multiple lists of readings and return the maximum reading values for the elements in aoiFeatures?

Given:

```
# FYI: 2.4 million elements in each of these lists in reality
allFeatures =  [101, 179, 181, 183, 185, 843, 845, 847, 849, 851] 
allReadings1 = [0.27, 0.25, 0.13, 0.04, 0.05, 0.09, 0.15, 0.13, 0.12, 0.20]
allReadings2 = [0.25, 0.06, 0.29, 0.29, 0.04, 0.21, 0.07, 0.06, 0.07, 0.06]
allReadings3 = [0.12, 0.02, 0.20, 0.27, 0.04, 0.08, 0.11, 0.24, 0.00, 0.13]
allReadings4 = [0.21, 0.00, 0.22, 0.11, 0.24, 0.16, 0.11, 0.18, 0.27, 0.14]
allReadings5 = [0.02, 0.18, 0.26, 0.22, 0.23, 0.15, 0.24, 0.28, 0.00, 0.07]
allReadings6 = [0.08, 0.25, 0.21, 0.23, 0.14, 0.21, 0.18, 0.09, 0.17, 0.27]
allReadings7 = [0.20, 0.02, 0.28, 0.16, 0.18, 0.27, 0.29, 0.19, 0.29, 0.13]
allReadings8 = [0.17, 0.01, 0.07, 0.23, 0.14, 0.20, 0.19, 0.01, 0.15, 0.17]
allReadings9 = [0.12, 0.18, 0.09, 0.10, 0.00, 0.03, 0.11, 0.03, 0.14, 0.14]
allReadings10 =[0.13, 0.03, 0.20, 0.13, 0.30, 0.30, 0.28, 0.12, 0.19, 0.22]

# FYI: 67,000 elements in this list in reality
aoiFeatures = [181, 843, 849]
```

Result:

```
181 0.29
843 0.27
849 0.29
```

Comment: @jezrael - Pandas loc[] times: Load 42MM elements: 0:01:07.8; Build max for 67K elements: 0:00:04.8

Comment: @piRSquared - Option #1 python max() times: Load 42MM elements: 0:00:02.2; Build max for 67K elements: 0:01:41.8

Comment: @piRSquared - Option #2 numpy max() times: Load 42MM elements: 0:00:02.2; Build max for 67K elements: 0:00:00.6

Comment: So, guys... why did it turn out this way? (Running 64-bit python 3.6 on Windows 10; 8 - i7 cores @ 3.6 GHz; 24 GBytes memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

You can let Python's `max` do the work and use `pandas.Series` to hold the results

```
readings = [allReadings1, allReadings2, allReadings3, allReadings4, allReadings5,
            allReadings6, allReadings7, allReadings8, allReadings9, allReadings10]

s = pd.Series(dict(zip(allFeatures, map(max, zip(*readings)))))
s[aoiFeatures]

181    0.29
843    0.30
849    0.29
dtype: float64
```

---

### Option 2

Or leverage Numpy

```
readings = [allReadings1, allReadings2, allReadings3, allReadings4, allReadings5,
            allReadings6, allReadings7, allReadings8, allReadings9, allReadings10]

s = pd.Series(np.max(readings, 0), allFeatures)
s[aoiFeatures]

181    0.29
843    0.30
849    0.29
dtype: float64
```

---

If you needed to update the array of maximums with a new reading

```
allReadings11 =[0.13, 0.03, 0.30, 0.13, 0.30, 0.30, 0.28, 0.12, 0.19, 0.22]
s[:] = np.maximum(s, allReadings11)

s[aoiFeatures]

181    0.29
843    0.30
849    0.29
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'm wondering now which would be the fastest... I'm guessing Option #2.  History: I found out how slow using pyodbc+cursor with a stored proc in SQL/Server is (32 minutes), so anything is an improvement at this point! I'll get the data (see FYI's) into all of these solutions and let you guys know.

Comment: @Jack sounds like you may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns and see if that offers anything you could use if your starting point is a SQL table...

Comment: @Jon Clements - Thanks! Starting point is a collection of masked arrays.

Answer (score 2):

First `zip` all lists together with `DataFrame` contructor and `index` parameter, select rows by `loc` and get `max` values:

```
L = list(zip(allReadings1,
             allReadings2,
             allReadings3,
             allReadings4,
             allReadings5,
             allReadings6,
             allReadings7,
             allReadings8,
             allReadings9,
             allReadings10))

df = pd.DataFrame(L, index=allFeatures)
print (df)
        0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
101  0.27  0.25  0.12  0.21  0.02  0.08  0.20  0.17  0.12  0.13
179  0.25  0.06  0.02  0.00  0.18  0.25  0.02  0.01  0.18  0.03
181  0.13  0.29  0.20  0.22  0.26  0.21  0.28  0.07  0.09  0.20
183  0.04  0.29  0.27  0.11  0.22  0.23  0.16  0.23  0.10  0.13
185  0.05  0.04  0.04  0.24  0.23  0.14  0.18  0.14  0.00  0.30
843  0.09  0.21  0.08  0.16  0.15  0.21  0.27  0.20  0.03  0.30
845  0.15  0.07  0.11  0.11  0.24  0.18  0.29  0.19  0.11  0.28
847  0.13  0.06  0.24  0.18  0.28  0.09  0.19  0.01  0.03  0.12
849  0.12  0.07  0.00  0.27  0.00  0.17  0.29  0.15  0.14  0.19
851  0.20  0.06  0.13  0.14  0.07  0.27  0.13  0.17  0.14  0.22

aoiFeatures = [181, 843, 849]
s = df.loc[aoiFeatures].max(axis=1)
print (s)
181    0.29
843    0.30
849    0.29
dtype: float64
```

Comment: LMAO... Alas, I expose my struggle building that dataframe for your amusement: # L = np.transpose(list(zip(allReadings1,allReadings2,allReadings3,allReadings4,allReadings5,allReadings6,allReadings7,allReadings8,allReadings9,allReadings10))) 15 minutes of my life I'll never get back, ugh!

Comment: @Jack you're lucky it was only 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and quick task:

```
pd.DataFrame([allReadings1, allReadings2,...],columns=allFeatures).max()
```

Sample output:

[image]